# Easiest way to copy a table from one database to another?

Tags: mysql, database

What is the best method to copy the data from a table in one database to a table in another database when the databases are under different users?

I know that I can use

```
INSERT INTO database2.table2 SELECT * from database1.table1
```

But here the problem is that both `database1` and `database2` are under different MySQL users. So `user1` can access `database1` only and `user2` can access `database2` only. Any idea?

Comment: You can give table level grants to users. see: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/grant.html

Comment: Unfortunately this wont work in my case, as I'm using a Godaddy shared hosting server. They wont allow to do such things with the database.

Comment: @mmdemirbas One table in the database has almost 1 million rows. The database dump will be huge. Also when I tried to export, only around 10000 rows are being exported - probably due to the large size.

Comment: I know you can use RENAME to move tables, and it's super quick. Is there an equivalent trick to copy tables?

Comment: BTW: You will need to take care that the field list is in the same order in both tables.  Otherwise it will be necessary to select the fields by name from the table in database1 so that they map to the correct fields in the table in database2.  This issue came up for me where I had backed up a database where table1 was modified after initial creation, and the new database where it was created from a mysqldump file.

Answer (score 147):

`CREATE TABLE db1.table1 SELECT * FROM db2.table1`

where db1 is the destination and db2 is the source

Comment: Does this work, if the two users do not have permissions to select data from each other?

Comment: this wont work across different mysql server though?

Comment: This doesn't copy over indexes

Comment: @Beryllium no this requires the user to have permissions for both DBs.  jaminator no this won't work across different servers, but I don't think the question was asking about that.  bcoughlan you are correct. this is a big flaw in this approach: It doesn't properly preserve the table structure.

Comment: My table was a Time Stamp and a few Small Ints.  I was root user of the MySql and had access to both DBs.  This approach worked perfectly for me preserving both the structure and content of the table.

Comment: The copied table did not have primary key and auto increment set. You have to run this after `ALTER TABLE db1.table1 ADD PRIMARY KEY (id); ALTER TABLE db1.table1 MODIFY COLUMN id INT AUTO_INCREMENT;`

Comment: imho, mysqldump is easier, as long as there is access to ssh, to avoid issues with missing indices.

Comment: doesn't answer the question though

Comment: To copy the indexes and objects you can use


`create table db1.table1 like db2.table1`

Comment: Please add this note from @bcoughlan as part of the answer if possible.

Just ended up wasting hours figuring why things slowed down only to see that indexes are not there.

Comment: @bcoughlan  I thing the method presented here could be a good way. The indexes can be added after that. Simply export only structure of database and all needed indexes you should have on the end of the query. Just run lines with ALTER TABLE commands and your tables will have correct table structure and indexes.

Answer (score 137):

If you have shell access you may use `mysqldump` to dump the content of `database1.table1` and pipe it to `mysql` to `database2`. The problem here is that `table1` is still `table1`.

```sh
mysqldump --user=user1 --password=password1 database1 table1 \
| mysql --user=user2 --password=password2 database2
```

Maybe you need to rename `table1` to `table2` with another query. On the other way you might use sed to change table1 to table2 between the to pipes.

```sh
mysqldump --user=user1 --password=password1 database1 table1 \
| sed -e 's/`table1`/`table2`/' \
| mysql --user=user2 --password=password2 database2
```

If table2 already exists, you might add the parameters to the first mysqldump which dont let create the table-creates.

```sh
mysqldump --no-create-info --no-create-db --user=user1 --password=password1 database1 table1 \
| sed -e 's/`table1`/`table2`/' \
| mysql --user=user2 --password=password2 database2
```

Comment: The problem with this is when it is automated you have to show the password.  If not automated and being done by user from command line it is ok.

Comment: @Nelles You can use any of the cascading user option files, oftentimes your local `~/.my.cnf` file, to store user and password information without having to reveal these values within the command itself. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/option-files.html

Answer (score 76):

If you are using ***PHPMyAdmin,*** it could be really simple.
Suppose you have following databases:

```
DB1 & DB2
```

DB1 have a table users which you like to copy to DB2

Under PHPMyAdmin, open DB1, then go to users table.

On this page, click on the **"Operations"** tab on the top right.
Under Operations, look for section **Copy table to (database.table):**

& you are done!

Comment: Dead simple! This is when I can celebrate being lazy!

Comment: You Save my time..i was doing naive approach..first exporting and then importing.

Comment: None of the other answers works, only yours that copies index as well

Comment: This would not work if the table was especially large, i.e. in excess of 4 GB. For example, I have a table which is 22GB that phpMyAdmin just cannot work with.

Comment: @MarkD Yes you are technically correct, this may not work for huge tables, though it could be handy for tables of decent size.

Comment: Perfect answer. Didnt know about this feature of phpmyadmin.

Comment: Great info. Smooth.

Comment: How can I handle this operation when I get a foreign key constraint. Can I edit the query somehow?

Comment: Super easy method !

Comment: @Christia I just tried this with phpMyAdmin 5.0.2 on a table with both "incoming" and "outgoing" foreign key constraints. After moving the table to another DB, both sets of constraints (on the moved table, and on those left behind that had constraints upon it) had been updated perfectly. (Nice to know - I didn't expect that to work myself!)

Answer (score 30):

### **[MySql Workbench](http://www.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/)**: Strongly Recommended

[image: Database Migration Tool From MySql Workbench]

This will easily handle migration problems. You can migrate selected tables of selected databases between MySql and SqlServer. You should give it a try definitely.

Comment: I'm about to give this a go, I have it setup but wonder if you've compared the `mysql Workbench` migration to `SQLYog`'s database copy? From my quick look it seems they are very similar, but mysql workbench is a newer feature

Comment: No, I didn't try SQLYog.

Comment: It is not apparent how to migrate to SQL Server from MySQL using MySql workbench.  I am in Workbench and find no clues from help or the UI.  I do know the SSMA for MySQL works for me.

Comment: Interesting, but the program caught doing the migration with a large database, the command line worked best.

Comment: @mmdemirbas, "*You can migrate selected tables of selected databases between MySql and SqlServer.*" The OP's question is not about SQL Server, though.

Comment: I mean this tool supports MySQL-to-MySQL migration as OP asked, and also supports MySQL-to-SQLServer, SQLServer-to-MySQL, SQLServer-to-SQLServer migrations. I wanted to make it explicit for someone else searching a similar solutions to use in other ways.

Answer (score 30):

I use Navicat for MySQL...

It makes all database manipulation easy !

You simply select both databases in Navicat and then use.

```
 INSERT INTO Database2.Table1 SELECT * from Database1.Table1
```

Comment: Used on SequelPro and worked perfectly. Thanks.

Answer (score 30):

it's worked good for me

```
CREATE TABLE dbto.table_name like dbfrom.table_name;
insert into  dbto.table_name select * from dbfrom.table_name;
```

Answer (score 14):

If your tables are on the same mysql server you can run the following

```
CREATE TABLE destination_db.my_table SELECT * FROM source_db.my_table;
ALTER TABLE destination_db.my_table ADD PRIMARY KEY (id); 
ALTER TABLE destination_db.my_table MODIFY COLUMN id INT AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

Comment: what about the other indexes ?! The question states to copy a table not only its data

Answer (score 13):

Here is another easy  way:

1. use DB1;   show create table TB1;

   - copy the syntax here in clipboard to create TB1 in DB2
2. use DB2;

   - paste the syntax here to create the table TB1

`INSERT INTO DB2.TB1  SELECT * from DB1.TB1;`

Comment: This helped me to automate the copying of a database, without having to use a gui program, thanks.

Answer (score 12):

I know this is old question, just answering so that anyone who lands here gets a better approach.

As of 5.6.10 you can do

```
CREATE TABLE new_tbl LIKE orig_tbl;
```

Refer documentation here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-like.html

Comment: It won't copy Data! Read the documentation you've referenced: > **CREATE TABLE ... LIKE does not preserve any DATA **

Answer (score 8):

Use MySql Workbench's Export and Import functionality.
Steps:
 1. Select the values you want

```
E.g. select * from table1;
```

2. Click on the Export button and save it as CSV.
3. create a new table using similar columns as the first one

   ```
   E.g. create table table2 like table1;
   ```
4. select all from the new table

   ```
   E.g. select * from table2;
   ```
5. Click on Import and select the CSV file you exported in step 2

[image: Sample of the Export and Import buttons in MySql Workbench]

Comment: It only works for tables with less than a billion rows i think.

Answer (score 4):

Try `mysqldbcopy` ([documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-utilities/1.3/en/mysqldbcopy.html))

Or you can create a "[federated table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/federated-use.html)" on your target host. Federated tables allow you to see a table from a different database server as if it was a local one. ([documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/federated-use.html))

After creating the federated table, you can copy data with the usual `insert into TARGET select * from SOURCE`

Comment: I've read about federated tables, but Amazon RDS (right now) doesn't have support for it... XP

Answer (score 4):

With MySQL Workbench you can use Data Export to dump just the table to a local SQL file (Data Only, Structure Only or Structure and Data) and then Data Import to load it into the other DB.

You can have multiple connections (different hosts, databases, users) open at the same time.

Answer (score 4):

One simple way to get all the queries you need is to use the data from information_schema and concat.

```sql
SELECT concat('CREATE TABLE new_db.', TABLE_NAME, ' LIKE old_db.', TABLE_NAME, ';') FROM `TABLES` WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'old_db';
```

You'll then get a list of results that looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE new_db.articles LIKE old_db.articles;
CREATE TABLE new_db.categories LIKE old_db.categories;
CREATE TABLE new_db.users LIKE old_db.users;
...
```

You can then just run those queries.

However it won't work with MySQL Views. You can avoid them by appending `AND TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'` from the initial query:

Answer (score 3):

First create the dump. Added the `--no-create-info --no-create-db` flags if `table2` already exists:

```
mysqldump -u user1 -p database1 table1 > dump.sql
```

Then enter `user1` password. Then:

```
sed -e 's/`table1`/`table2`/' dump.sql
```

```
mysql -u user2 -p database2 < dump.sql
```

Then enter `user2` password.

Same as [helmor's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12243188/866022) but the approach is more secure as passwords aren't exposed in raw text to the console (reverse-i-search, password sniffers, etc). Other approach is fine if it's executed from a script file with appropriate restrictions placed on it's permissions.

Answer (score 2):

Is this something you need to do regularly, or just a one off?

You can do an export (eg using phpMyAdmin or similar) that will script out your table and its contents to a text file, then you could re-import that into the other Database.

Comment: I need to do it only once. But the problem is the table in the database has almost 1 million rows. The database dump will be huge. Also when I tried to export, only around 10000 rows are being exported - probably due to the large size.

Comment: Ah, yes that's a limitation. [This WordPress Codex article](http://codex.wordpress.org/Backing_Up_Your_Database) might help?  It's a wordpress article, but might provide you with some insight (there's a section on how to dump tables using command line, in the case where the DB is too big for phpMyAdmin to handle).

Comment: The mysqldump command line tool has no problems with 1 million rows, or several billion rows - all that will affect is how much time it takes and how much of your hard drive the result occupies (assuming you output it to a file).  My experience with phpMyAdmin's export command is that it's much more limited than mysqldump.

Answer (score 1):

use below steps to copy and insert some columns from one database table to another database table-

1. CREATE TABLE tablename ( columnname datatype (size), columnname datatype (size));

2.INSERT INTO db2.tablename SELECT columnname1,columnname2 FROM db1.tablename;

Answer (score 1):

For me I need to specific schema to "information_schema.TABLES"

for example.

```
SELECT concat('CREATE TABLE new_db.', TABLE_NAME, ' LIKE old_db.', TABLE_NAME, ';') FROM information_schema.TABLES  WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'old_db';
```

Comment: Hi poomcyber, can you confirm that your post is an attempt to answer the question at the top of the page with a solution? To me it gives an impression of being a request for help with your own, similar but slightly different problem.

Answer (score 0):

IN xampp just export the required table as a .sql file and then import it to the required

Answer (score -2):

**create table destination_customer like sakila.customer**(Database_name.tablename), this will only copy the structure of the source table, for data also to get copied with the structure do this **create table destination_customer as select * from sakila.customer**

Comment: This seems to be an answer to a totally different question.  There's no `CREATE TABLE LIKE` in the question, so why mention that it's wrong?  And there's no explanation of *how* this answer solves the problem that neither user has access to the tables of the other.