# How to copy a table and its relationship tables from one database to another in SQL

Tags: sql-server, database, database-design, relationship

I have TableA which has columns ID1, ID2, C1, C2, C3, C4 and I copied them into TableB as

SET IDENTIY_INSERT TableB ON

Insert into TableB (ID1, ID2, C1, C2, C3, C4)

Select ID1, ID2, C1, C2, C3, C4 FROM TableA

SET IDENTIY_INSERT TableB OFF

This does copy the row but how do I copy the TableC automatically which is referred by ID2, that has relationship with Table A.

That is when I copy TableA into TableB which is in another database, I want the other database to be populated with both TableA and TableC

Comment: I would use SSMS Export Wizard to generate the proper scripts to create the tables in the other database *and* import the data.  Or perhaps I'm misunderstanding what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: Refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12242772/easiest-way-to-copy-a-table-from-one-database-to-another. This might help!

Comment: @itsme.cvk not sure that other question will help much here. This is tagged sql-server and that other one is mysql.

Comment: @devlincarnate I have scripts of tables already created in other database, I just want to populate those tables with data from another similar database. I am able to copy data from one table and I like to know if there is a way I can automatically copy the tables which has relationship with this table.

Comment: If you want to copy data you have to run a query to do it. There is no way to automatically copy data from a table related to another table. Do you really need to keep multiple copies of this data or could you just reference the data remotely?

Comment: what about using replication or log shipping to transfer the data?

Comment: @SeanLange I need to keep multiple copies of data and looks like there is no automatic way to do it and I am running query to do it.Thanks

Comment: If you need to copy data routinely you could look into replication. It is really challenging to offer much help here because there is not much information.