# Unicode data is not saved in right format in sql database using webapi

Tags: sql, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

When I am trying to save Unicode data such as Chinese in my database it is saving as question marks `???????` in the sql database table.

```
    public  IHttpActionResult SaveSelections(UserPreference model)
    {
        var user = db.UserPreferences.FirstOrDefault(p => p.UserName == model.UserName);
        //var psellers= db.PSellers.ToArray();
        if (user == null)
        {
            try
            {
                db.UserPreferences.Add(model);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return BadRequest(e.Message);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                user.AreaText = model.AreaText;
                user.RegionText = model.RegionText;                    

                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return BadRequest(e.Message);
            }

        }
        return Ok();
    }
```

Comment: Did you create database with UTF8 encoding? If you did not specify it, the default is ASCII.

Comment: NO i have not created as UTF8 encoding

Comment: Then that is your problem. You cannot store unicode characters in database with ASCII encoding. The safest way it would be to create new database with unicode encoding and transfer current data to the new database. Will post as an answer...

Answer (score 0):

Your database, as you said it in comment to your question, does **not** accept UTF8 but ASCII. What you have to do in order for database to accept unicode characters is run the following command:

```
CREATE DATABASE mydatabase CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

For more info see [Database Character Set and Collation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-database.html).

So basically, create new database and transfer current data to it. If you don't know how to do that, the answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12242772/easiest-way-to-copy-a-table-from-one-database-to-another).

Comment: Will this work in Sql server? because i was not able to create utf8 database

Comment: Oh, you are using SQL Server. Above is for MySQL. SQL Server's default charset when creating database is UTF8. But instead of `varchar` you have to use `nvarchar`

Comment: nvarchar also dont work if i insert "(주)타이호인스트-KR" then in table it will be updated as "(?)??????-KR"