# Mysql InnoDB table status in use can not be open

Tags: mysql, innodb

I have an issue with InnoDB tables. all table status are showing in use.

I am trying to open table but it is giving error "Table 'mysqlbackup.aadhars' doesn't exist in engine"
[image]

please help me

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the table belongs to different schema (and not `mysqlbackup`) I would recommend checking all the table names (along with schemas) and see which schema `aadhars` table belongs to, e.g.:

```
SELECT *
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_schema = 'mysqlbackup';
```

The above query will return the names of all the tables present in `mysqlbackup` schema. If you want to see which schema `aadhars` belongs to, try the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_name = 'aadhars';
```

Comment: If I am running first comment table comment for the first table is
Table 'mysqlbackup.aadhars' doesn't exist in engine

How can I back or restore data

Comment: If the table exists in different schema then you can (a) reference schema name along with table name in the query or (b) copy the table across schema, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12242772/easiest-way-to-copy-a-table-from-one-database-to-another