# Node JS How to change key names in an object using another object for conversion?

Tags: mysql, node.js, sql-server

I have these tables on one DB (MySQL) which I need to sync with corresponding tables on another DB (MSSQL), but the field names are different. I was wondering what efficient way there is to convert the names of the fields after fetching the rows so that I could insert them into the other tables.

I was thinking of doing something like this. Make objects where the key is the original table column's names and the value is the destination table column's names:

```
{
name : UNAME
id : CID
location : LOC
}
```

And the rows that I fetched and need to insert would look something like this:

```
{
name: Ethan
id: 1234
location: somewhere1
},
{
name: Jhon
id: 5678
location: somewhere2
}
```

and then run on these objects and change their key names according to the conversion table, so that I can insert them to the destination table properly.

I can't just insert without field names, as the fields are not in the same order.
How can I do what I've described efficiently? Do you have ideas for better strategies to accomplish this?

thanks a lot!

Comment: Did you try this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12242772/easiest-way-to-copy-a-table-from-one-database-to-another?

Comment: @DipakC, unfortunately, it's not possible, because (1) they aren't on the same DB (2) one is MySQL and the other is MSSQL, and (3) I don't need to copy the table as it is, eventually it'd be a scheduled job that needs to check certain things and on that basis to copy to the other table

Comment: Then programming might better option. But understand that construct the object carefully with field name.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds about right, how about this:

```
const converter = {
  name : UNAME
  id : CID
  location : LOC
}

let newData = []

dbResults.forEach(row => {
  newData.push({
    name: `${row[converter['name']]}`
    id: `${row[converter['id']]}`
    location: `${row[converter['location']]}`
  })
})
```

EDIT:
Actually looking at the above code there is no need for the converter object:

```
let newData = []

dbResults.forEach(row => {
  newData.push({
    name: `${row['UNAME']}`
    id: `${row['CID']}`
    location: `${row['LOC]}`
  })
})
```

Comment: thanks, but that's not exactly what I'm trying to do, plus I need it to be more like a general function to be usable on many tables, that's why I need the conversion tables. I need to iterate each row and change its name according to the conversion table without explicitly specifying the names