# Is it ok to store DB password for the production environment in the config/database.yml file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Is it ok to store DB password for the production environment in the "config/database.yml" file? Or is there any more correct way to do it (maybe environment variables)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a good idea! One main reason is that the `config/database.yml` file will probably be included in some kind of source control, like a git repository. Even if the repo is private currently, you can't know for sure it won't be made public in the future and then you would have a problem on your hands!

In addition, if anyone ever gains read-access to your application's files or just a copy of your application's source, they now have your database password.

A typical solution is to set an environment variable like you suggested and then read it in the .yml file:

```
password: <%= ENV['DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>
```

If you're using a PaaS like Heroku, this is the standard way to do things. But even [this isn't a perfect solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12461484/is-it-secure-to-store-passwords-as-environment-variables-rather-than-as-plain-t), so evaluate your options carefully.