# Post Request To Slack Endpoint Failing

Tags: ruby, curl, slack

I have making a post request in Ruby to a slack endpoint and its failing, here is my request, not sure what I'm missing:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
#Notification Script Test

def send_slack_message
    slack_rooms = [ '#test_channel_notify' ]
    slack_token_file = (File.join(ENV['HOME'], '.slack_api_token'))
    slack_api_token = (File.open(@slack_token_file).readlines)[0].chomp
    msg = 'This is a test message send'
    slack_url = "https://slack.com/api/chat.postMessage"
    %x{curl -k -X POST -d"token=#{slack_api_token}\&channel=#{slack_rooms}\&text=#{msg}" '#{slack_url}'} 
end

send_slack_message
```

I am getting the following error, not sure what I'm missing:

```
./cap2.rb:7:in `initialize': no implicit conversion of nil into String (TypeError)
from ./cap2.rb:7:in `open'
from ./cap2.rb:7:in `send_slack_message'
from ./cap2.rb:13:in `<main>'
```

I am a ruby novice so I may be missing everything would love some help!

Comment: `slack_token_file` not `@slack_token_file`

Comment: I saw it immediately after I posted this..LOL. Im curious if you see anything wrong with my actual post request, as the curl is returning properly but nothing is getting posted to the channel I created.

Answer (score 2):

The error says that you can't give `nil` to `File.open`. Make sure `@slack_token_file` exists and is not nil.

Comment: Yup I saw that as you posted this response. I removed the @ since its not a global variable and I'm not getting that error anymore!

Comment: Im curious if you see anything wrong with my actual post request, as the curl is returning properly but nothing is getting posted to the channel I created.

Comment: @user2019182 That's another question ;)

Answer (score 1):

The slack API wants to receive the payload in this format: 'payload={"json": "data"}'
Using Net::HTTP you can make a POST request like this:

```
require 'net/http'
require 'uri'

def payload(message, channel)
  { channel: channel, username: 'your-username', text: message, icon_emoji: ':robot_face:' }
end

msg = 'This is a test message send'
body = payload(msg, '#test_channel_notify').to_json

url = URI("https://slack.com/api/chat.postMessage")
http = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port)
http.use_ssl = true
http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(url)
request.body = "payload=#{body}"
http.request(request)
```

Answer (score 0):

While your original problem has been solved, I will provide an *alternative* solution which follows the more common practice of storing secret credentials [as environment variables, not as files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12461484/is-it-secure-to-store-passwords-as-environment-variables-rather-than-as-plain-t) (which can, for example, more easily exfiltrated by accident, committed to source control, [pasted to a presentation](https://mobile.twitter.com/codepo8/status/857233206927601665), etc).

Set `SLACK_TOKEN` in your environment, and then use:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
#Notification Script Test

def send_slack_message
    slack_rooms = [ '#test_channel_notify' ]
    slack_api_token = ENV['SLACK_TOKEN']
    msg = 'This is a test message send'
    slack_url = "https://slack.com/api/chat.postMessage"
    %x{curl -k -X POST -d"token=#{slack_api_token}\&channel=#{slack_rooms}\&text=#{msg}" '#{slack_url}'} 
end

send_slack_message
```