# Correctly hiding database credentials

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, security, mongoose

As you may see, I have my db connection file and another "protected" file, where my credentials are, and this file is included in .gitignore. I import it and reach the data. Quite basic. Therefore my questions are:

1. Is this the right way to do it?
2. If not, how should I do it? Plus: how could I add extra security to my account,connection?
3. Let's suppose I have a private collection, that no one should see, how could I protect specially this collection? I mean, with a password or a two step verification let's say.

Current code:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const mongoCredentials = require("../protected/mongoCredential");

const URI = `mongodb+srv://${mongoCredentials.username}:${mongoCredential.password}
              @firstcluster-eldi8.mongodb.net/culturapp?retryWrites=true&w=majority`;

mongoose.connect(URI, { useUnifiedTopology: true, useNewUrlParser: true })
  .then(db => console.log("MongoDB is connected"))
  .catch(err => console.log(">> ERROR: ",err));

module.exports = mongoose;
```

Comment: Please, do not post pictures instead of code....you can use some sort of environment variables in order to accomplish that, using `process.env`

Comment: Thank you! Will take into account the next time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ...I have my db connection file and another "protected" file, where my credentials are, and this file is included in .gitignore. I import it and reach the data..

The correct way to do it is to use [envrironmental variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable).

### Use environmental variables

Environmental variables are set on the *environment*, i.e your local development machine or the remote production server.
Then, within your app, you read the environment variables and use them appropriately.

There's (at least) a couple reasons it's usually done like this:

- The credentials don't exist in a file that can be read by someone viewing the repository contents. Someone cloning the repository doesn't need to know *your* database credentials.
- The credentials are likely different between environments. You are likely using a different database on your local development machine and a different database in your remote production server.

Here's how you set environment variables (this is for Linux, other OS's might be different):

```
$ export MONGO_DB_USERNAME=foo
$ export MONGO_DB_PASSWORD=bar
```

and here's how you read them within Node.js:

```
console.log(process.env.MONGO_DB_USERNAME) // logs 'foo'
console.log(process.env.MONGO_DB_PASSWORD) // logs 'bar'
```

### or pass variables to the process when starting up

Alternatively, you can pass variables when starting up the process like so:

```
$ MONGO_DB_USERNAME=foo MONGO_DB_PASSWORD=bar node app.js
```

However that's generally discouraged since you're most probably starting your process through the [npm start script](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/start.html). Since `package.json`, where the `npm start` command is defined, is always committed to the repository it defeats the whole purpose of hiding the credentials.

Comment: Well....Amazing answer, thanks for your help! Completely understood.

Comment: ok and what will happen in my server reboots, do I need to set those env variables again?

Answer (score 1):

Like you mentioned along lines, using environment variables is more like security through obfuscation.

I would try to have the credentials in a separate configuration file. With a bit of design, encrypt this file and store those keys in secure enclaves or TPMs.

[Check this thread.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12461484/is-it-secure-to-store-passwords-as-environment-variables-rather-than-as-plain-t)