# How to store GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS in an AWS ECS environment on Fargate?

Tags: amazon-web-services, environment-variables, amazon-ecs, google-authentication, firebase-admin

We have an API app that uses Firebase Admin to send messages to devices.
Earlier, we used to specify the service account key using environment variable like GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="path_to_file.json".
But now, since we are shifting to AWS Elastic Container Service on Fargate, I am unable to figure out how to put this file in the container for AWS ECS.

Any advice highly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved it by storing the service key as a JSON Stringified environment variable & using `admin.credential.cert()` instead of defaultAppCredentials.
Refer: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.credential#cert

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest instead AWS Secrets Manager that is purpose-built for storing secrets. Take a look to his blog post:

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/securing-credentials-using-aws-secrets-manager-with-aws-fargate/

Comment: Are you suggesting to put the entire json as a secret value? We are already using AWS Secrets Manager for other environment variables, but as suggested on https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started#setting_the_environment_variable, the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS needs to be a file path. How should I put a new file after the image is already built?

Comment: As long as you keep it within Secrets Manager Quotas, there will not be a problem to do that. (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/userguide/reference_limits.html)

Comment: Solved it by storing the service key as an environment variable & using admin.credential.cert() instead of defaultAppCredentials. Refer: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.credential#cert

Answer (score 0):

Even better than using environment variables which have their own [downsides](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12461484/2579733), you can leverage AWS Parameter Store which is a secure way to manage secrets in the AWS environment (where secrets are encrypted both in transit and at rest).

You'd need to create an IAM role for Amazon ECS for your code to have access to the Parameter Store.

You may want to check this article: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/managing-secrets-for-amazon-ecs-applications-using-parameter-store-and-iam-roles-for-tasks/

Answer (score 0):

Use the specific method `from_service_account_info` as described [here](https://googleapis.dev/python/google-auth/latest/reference/google.auth._jwt_async.html?highlight=from_service_account_info#google.auth._jwt_async.Credentials.from_service_account_info). You then pass the content of the credentials json file as a dictionary.