# How do I publish a package to npm using an API key?

Tags: npm, npm-publish

NPM gives the ability to [create access tokens](https://docs.npmjs.com/about-access-tokens) with the right to publish packages to the NPM registry, assuming that you've set the package settings to "Require two-factor authentication or automation tokens" in "Publishing access" (and so implicitly it requires 2FA to be enabled, I assume).

How do I use this token to publish? I've checked the output of `npm publish` -- it asks for an OTP code, either as a prompt or a flag, and before I enabled 2FA it asked me for my password again. Using a fixed token would be easier than having to pull up my authenticator app. I could disable 2FA, but getting the token working is preferable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The npm registry has 3 different kinds of token: Read-only, Automation, and Publish.

It sounds like you created a Publish token. You need to create an Automation token instead, since this is the only one that bypasses 2FA.

Comment: That was it. The other key bit of information is that you can't use the CLI to create these tokens: you have to use the GUI on the website.

Answer (score 4):

For verdaccio or similar you can use this:

```
> npm config set registry http://verdaccio/npm/

# then create and update local .npmrc file:
> npm config set _authToken=%YOUR_ACCES_TOKEN%

# and publish pointing to your registry
> npm publish --registry http://verdaccio/npm/
```

For proget:

```
[~]$ npm config set registry http://proget/npm/private-npm

[~]$ npm config set always-auth true
[~]$ npm config set _auth {ENCODEDAPIKEY}
[~]$ npm config set email {email address}

# then as usual
[~]$npm publish --registry {YOUR_REGISTRY}
```

Instructions are [here proget](https://docs.inedo.com/docs/proget/feeds/npm?utm_source=proget&utm_medium=product&utm_campaign=proget5) and [here verdaccio](https://imhazige.medium.com/use-verdaccio-to-publish-npm-package-to-a-local-repository-d086f11bc3fb)

Comment: Can these be done as environment variables rather than writing to the `.npmrc`?

Comment: Yes, but it's more secure to use local config file

Comment: I'd argue it's more secure to use env variable.

Comment: Sure, I'm not going to argue about that, someone else already did it =)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12461484/is-it-secure-to-store-passwords-as-environment-variables-rather-than-as-plain-t