# Daily export mySql table to folder/url

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mySql table that I am filling with info from a form. I would like to export the table each day as a csv. I would like this csv to be accessible via a url so my client could simply enter the url and retrieve/download the csv.

For example, the survey is hosted at

survey.mywebsite.com

I would like the client/admin to be able to access the most recent data by going to

survey.mywebsite.com/data/mostRecent.csv

Assuming my connection php looks like this

```
        $hostname = "hostname";
        $username = "admin";
        $dbname = "dbName";

        //These variable values need to be changed by you before deploying
        $password = "password";
        $usertable = "surveyTable";         

        //Connecting database
        mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) OR DIE ("Unable to 
        connect to database! Please try again later.");

        mysql_select_db($dbname);
```

How would I dump the table named 'surveyTable' to the folder survey.mywebsite.com/data/ each day?

I am a total rookie with php so please walk me through this as gently as possible

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to output MySQL query results in csv format?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/356578/how-to-output-mysql-query-results-in-csv-format)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to export a table like so

```
SELECT * INTO OUTFILE "data/mostRecent.csv"
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY "\n"
FROM surveyTable;
```

Referenced from http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html

You can then simple point to the exported file with a link(assuming you have it within your webroot). Alternatively, you could set headers, and then fpassthru it