# Export MySQL table in which row values contains only NULL value

Tags: php, mysql

In want to export MySQL table which contains 1M+ records, now I want to figured out those records which is having `NULL` values and also export those values only which satisfy my criteria.

Is this possible, with PHP script or from MySQL console or whatever?

Comment: sql can do it. but can you provide more detail example?

Comment: example. which result from your table null value need to execute.

Answer (score 1):

You can use mysqldump to do it. It allows you to specify databaee and table and the --where parameter allows you to specify a where-clause.

See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html

Answer (score 1):

### You can use MYSQL workbench to export the record

1) for Null value record only

```
select * from tablename where col is null
```

2) your criteria

```
select * from tablename where your <criteria logic>
```

You can export this result set from workbench to csv or excel

You can also use TOAD for MYSQL

refer
[How to export table data in MySql Workbench to csv?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17113812/how-to-export-table-data-in-mysql-workbench-to-csv)

Comment: +1, thanks but still am having problem with exporting, but will manage