# joined query output to csv file in mysql workbench?

Tags: mysql

I know you can export a table from mysql workbench easily however how do I output joined table to csv file?

I've checked [How to export table data in MySql Workbench to csv?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17113812/how-to-export-table-data-in-mysql-workbench-to-csv) and following its suggestions tried

```
select
  *
  INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/products.csv'
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
  ENCLOSED BY '"'
  ESCAPED BY '\\'
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
from table_1 t_1
left join table_2 t_2 
  on t_1.id= t_2.u_id;
```

which does not seem to work.

I've tried querying

```
select
  *
from table_1 t_1
left join join table_2 t_2 
  on t_1.id= t_2.u_id;
```

and simply using Export in mysql workbench but it only outputs 1000rows. I know that you can change the limit but my dataset if very large.

How to output to csv?

Answer (score 0):

Your question lacks few details.

If you had tried the first command

```
select
  *
  INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/products.csv'
  ...
```

workbench (or so), you might have missed the error message - **OR ELSE you missed to post the error here**

1. Check if --secure-file-priv option is set. And you shall run your first choice itself.
2. If you run your second choice and then export from workbench, increase this

> MySQL Workbench >> Edit >> Preferences >> SQL Queries tab >> Query
>   Results (Limit Rows).