# I need retrive all data of id by rows on MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

i have a table(MySQL) with ~35.000.000 rows, and i need retrieve all data in order by id.

Table: data

```
+--+-----+-----+
|id|field|value|
+--+-----+-----+
|1 |  x  |  10 |
+--+-----+-----+
|1 | y   |  12 |
+--+-----+-----+
|2 | x   |  24 |
+--+-----+-----+
|2 | y   |  25 |
+--+-----+-----+
|3 | z   |  1  |
+--+-----+-----+
|3 | a   |  4  |
+--+-----+-----+
|3 | b   | 7.1 |
+--+-----+-----+
```

I need retrieve:

```
+--+--+----+
|10|12|NULL|    <--- ID:1
+--+--+----+
|24|25|NULL|    <--- ID:2
+--+--+----+
|1 | 4|7.1 |    <--- ID:3
+--+--+----+
```

My Query:

```
SELECT
(
    SELECT
        value
    FROM
        data
    WHERE
        EXISTS(
            SELECT
                1
            FROM
                members
            WHERE
                data.id = members.id
            LIMIT 1
        )
)
```

My Result:

```
#1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s)
```

Any idea how to do this, only MySQL and efficiently?

Comment: How does your query relate to the desired results?  The desired results have three columns but your query only has two.  The desired results all seem to be from the `value` column, but your query has `field` and `value`.

Comment: I dont belive that it's all - select from select... just like that.

Comment: Is it always up to three rows per id?

Comment: What do the three columns in your result set represent? Why does the 'a' value for id 3 go in the same column as the 'y' value for id 1? You need to explain what you are trying to do in a clearer fashion.

Comment: This problem doesn't seem to have any logic in it. You're trying to turn one column into three, with a query that produces two, and presents all the data without any sort of context *at all*. What are you trying to accomplish here?

Comment: can you provide table structure and sample data as SQL?

Comment: sorry, i update the sql query... and i tried with GROUP_CONCAT()...

Comment: @OlafErlandsenTriskel Do you need GROUP_CONCAT or many columns?

Comment: i need only value column, but all value column in one row by id...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get your desired output as you stated it in your question (values in separate columns) you can use a query like this

```
SELECT r.id,
       MAX(CASE WHEN r.rnum = 1 THEN value END) value1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN r.rnum = 2 THEN value END) value2,
       MAX(CASE WHEN r.rnum = 3 THEN value END) value3
  FROM
(
  SELECT id, rnum
    FROM
  (
    SELECT DISTINCT id
      FROM runnerdata
  ) d CROSS JOIN
  (
    SELECT 1 rnum UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 UNION ALL
    SELECT 3
  ) n
) r LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT id, value, @n := IF(@g = id, @n + 1, 1) rnum, @g := id
    FROM runnerdata
   ORDER BY id, data
) q ON r.id = q.id
   AND r.rnum = q.rnum
 GROUP BY r.id
```

Output:

```
| ID | VALUE1 | VALUE2 | VALUE3 |
|----|--------|--------|--------|
|  1 |     10 |     12 | (null) |
|  2 |     24 |     25 | (null) |
|  3 |      4 |    7.1 |      1 |
```

**Note:** *It won't be blazing fast.*

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/453426/5)** demo

---

Now with `GROUP_CONCAT()` your query might look like

```
SELECT id, GROUP_CONCAT(value ORDER BY data) data_values
  FROM runnerdata
 GROUP BY id
```

Output:

```
| ID |    DATA_VALUES |
|----|----------------|
|  1 |    10.00,12.00 |
|  2 |    24.00,25.00 |
|  3 | 4.00,7.10,1.00 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/453426/3)** demo

Then in your client code `explode` values of `data_values` column while iterating over the resultsest and produce the desired output.

Comment: @That's **exactly** what I showed in my second example with `GROUP_CONCAT`. All values are packed as a delimited list in `data_values` column per id. Or did you mean something else?

Answer (score 1):

As you said in the comments:

```
i need only value column, but all value column in one row by id.
```

In this case you can use GROUP_CONCAT function. I simplified your case to the minimal working example:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM data;
+----+-------+
| id | value |
+----+-------+
|  1 | 1     |
|  1 | 2     |
|  2 | 3     |
|  2 | 4     |
|  2 | 5     |
+----+-------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

SELECT
    data.id,
    GROUP_CONCAT(data.value)
FROM
    data
GROUP BY
    data.id;

gives this:

+----+--------------------------+
| id | GROUP_CONCAT(data.value) |
+----+--------------------------+
|  1 | 1,2                      |
|  2 | 3,4,5                    |
+----+--------------------------+
```

SQL fiddle temporarily unavailable, so giving you CREATE TABLE statement:

```
CREATE TABLE `data` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `value` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `data` VALUES (1,'1'), (1, '2'),(2,'3'),(2,'4'),(2,'5');
```

Comment: i need value to convert CSV:
"value","values2","value3","value 4\"","value5"\n

Comment: @OlafErlandsenTriskel If you are using php after receiving the data from SQL, you can convert in to CSV. Or output to CSV file directly from mysql: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/356578/how-to-output-mysql-query-results-in-csv-format