# Is it possible to export an SQL queries results into a document from the client side

Tags: mysql, sql

I am just wondering if it possible to export an SQL query results into some kind of document that you can externally read from my questions really are:

Can this be done?
What type of file would it be?
Does anyone now any tutorials?
Has this been done with Mssql, MySQL, or some other type of SQL?

I was wondering if this can be done with only code no user interface so for example not using PhpMyaAdmins options to export this i was wondering something along the lines of press a button and it sends all the results into a file that is some where the user can get to.

Comment: Please look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/356578/how-to-output-mysql-query-results-in-csv-format) for assistance.

Comment: Sorry but, the way you've composed your question, you're basically asking if it's possible to read back the information you've stored into a database. (And the answer is "yes", unless you are using the [BLACKHOLE storage engine](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/blackhole-storage-engine.html)).

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario I understand that you can read back the information im not trying to get it to display on the screen i am trying to get it to go into the external document just by using code whether this is using php, sql, or any other type of code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like the following:

```
SELECT sale, del
INTO OUTFILE 'C:/tmp/orders.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
FROM order;
```

**[Source](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select-into.html)**

Comment: just wondering what file types can this be exported as is it just CSV or can it send to txt or excel document

Comment: I have used this query and it is working fine and exporting to a CSV file just wondering what other file formats it can export to ?

Comment: Yes, you can export it to a .txt file.  From my knowledge, you have to export to CSV and then convert it if you want an Excel file.

Answer (score 2):

You can export results into excel (as a .rpt file) or .txt by clicking the appropriate 'results to button'

shortcuts are: ctrl+T for text and ctrl+SHIFT+F for excel

Comment: Response is for Microsoft SQL Server 2012

Comment: I am trying to do this is client side not server side so if you was on the web you press the button then it sends the details to a file.

Comment: There are likely several options, one I've seen used is SSRS (SQL Server Reporting Services reports) see http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522712.aspx

These reports allow for returned results to be exported into a number or formats (xml, csv, pdf, MHTML, excel, TIFF, and word).