# PHP MySQL Select Command: using the '\n' in it

Tags: php, mysql

When I try using something like

`$aSqlCommand = "SELECT ............. '\n'";`

The quote continues on after the double quote, now that's probably because it's an escape character right? How can I change it so the quote will stop?

I want to use the LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' in it.

Full Query:

```
$sql2= "SELECT date,value,domain
INTO OUTFILE 'export1.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'";
```

From: [How to output MySQL query results in CSV format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356578/how-to-output-mysql-query-results-in-csv-format)
and
http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/1475/save-mysql-query-results-into-a-text-or-csv-file/

Comment: Why do you need a `\n` in your query ?

Comment: Can you provide your whole query?

Comment: I second this, there's no need to prettify the query. Is it perhaps within data you're trying to insert?

Comment: To use LINES TERMINATED BY

Comment: please post the full querry

Comment: Does `\n` really need to be present when handling strings? Why not replace it with something safe like `str_replace("\n", ' nlb ', $str)` to later replace back into a line break like `str_replace(' nlb ', "\n", $str)` if you have to use it. Assuming no one would ever write " nlb " you are save to use that as a key.

Comment: We need to see your full query in order to make an informed decision but the likelihood is you've missed out an ' somewhere in the query.

Comment: The full query is up there and the links from where basically it came.

Comment: @Strj500 Try my method. `TERMINATE BY ' nlb '` and then when displaying the code or writing it to your CSV you simply run the replacement to transform back into a line break.

Comment: There must be a simple way to negate the '\' character to allow it's use in this MySQL query. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape `\` and `"` as following:

`$sql2 = "SELECT date,value,domain INTO OUTFILE 'export1.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\\n'";`

Answer (score -1):

You need to escape the `"` from `ENCLOSED BY` and `\n` from `LINES TERMINATED BY`, just like this:

```
"SELECT date,value,domain INTO OUTFILE 'export1.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\\n'"
```

Comment: i dont think you understood the question

Comment: Why did you negative my answer? for what i can see my explanation fits his doubt. Please review your reason for your vote...