# How can I pull values at 15 minutes interval from multiple tables?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I have many, many tables (with same designs, each table equates a day) full of time stamped values and I need to pull out the values that appear at every fifteen minute interval so that I can export them to a CSV.  Is there a way of looping through the records, iterating the where clause, and inserting them into a temporary table that would work for this?

This is what I'm currently using:

```
(SELECT dtProcessedUTC, binData
FROM `timecull_010109` 
where TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '00:00:00' AND '00:00:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '00:15:00' AND '00:15:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '00:30:00' AND '00:30:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '00:45:00' AND '00:45:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '01:00:00' AND '01:00:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '01:15:00' AND '01:15:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '01:30:00' AND '01:30:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '01:45:00' AND '01:45:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '02:00:00' AND '02:00:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '02:15:00' AND '02:15:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '02:30:00' AND '02:30:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '02:45:00' AND '02:45:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '03:00:00' AND '03:00:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '03:15:00' AND '03:15:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '03:30:00' AND '03:30:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '03:45:00' AND '03:45:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '04:00:00' AND '04:00:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '04:15:00' AND '04:15:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '04:30:00' AND '04:30:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '04:45:00' AND '04:45:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '05:00:00' AND '05:00:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '05:15:00' AND '05:15:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '05:30:00' AND '05:30:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '05:45:00' AND '05:45:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '06:00:00' AND '06:00:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '06:15:00' AND '06:15:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '06:30:00' AND '06:30:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '06:45:00' AND '06:45:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '07:00:00' AND '07:00:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '07:15:00' AND '07:15:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '07:30:00' AND '07:30:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '07:45:00' AND '07:45:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '08:00:00' AND '08:00:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '08:15:00' AND '08:15:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '08:30:00' AND '08:30:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '08:45:00' AND '08:45:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '09:00:00' AND '09:00:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '09:15:00' AND '09:15:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '09:30:00' AND '09:30:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '09:45:00' AND '09:45:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '10:00:00' AND '10:00:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '10:15:00' AND '10:15:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '10:30:00' AND '10:30:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '10:45:00' AND '10:45:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '11:00:00' AND '11:00:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '11:15:00' AND '11:15:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '11:30:00' AND '11:30:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '11:45:00' AND '11:45:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '12:00:00' AND '12:00:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '12:15:00' AND '12:15:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '12:30:00' AND '12:30:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '12:45:00' AND '12:45:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '13:00:00' AND '13:00:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '13:15:00' AND '13:15:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '13:30:00' AND '13:30:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '13:45:00' AND '13:45:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '14:00:00' AND '14:00:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '14:15:00' AND '14:15:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '14:30:00' AND '14:30:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '14:45:00' AND '14:45:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '15:00:00' AND '15:00:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '15:15:00' AND '15:15:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '15:30:00' AND '15:30:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '15:45:00' AND '15:45:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '16:00:00' AND '16:00:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '16:15:00' AND '16:15:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '16:30:00' AND '16:30:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '16:45:00' AND '16:45:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '17:00:00' AND '17:00:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '17:15:00' AND '17:15:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '17:30:00' AND '17:30:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '17:45:00' AND '17:45:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '18:00:00' AND '18:00:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '18:15:00' AND '18:15:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '18:30:00' AND '18:30:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '18:45:00' AND '18:45:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '19:00:00' AND '19:00:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '19:15:00' AND '19:15:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '19:30:00' AND '19:30:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '19:45:00' AND '19:45:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '20:00:00' AND '20:00:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '20:15:00' AND '20:15:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '20:30:00' AND '20:30:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '20:45:00' AND '20:45:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '21:00:00' AND '21:00:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '21:15:00' AND '21:15:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '21:30:00' AND '21:30:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '21:45:00' AND '21:45:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '22:00:00' AND '22:00:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '22:15:00' AND '22:15:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '22:30:00' AND '22:30:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '22:45:00' AND '22:45:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '23:00:00' AND '23:00:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '23:15:00' AND '23:15:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '23:30:00' AND '23:30:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '23:45:00' AND '23:45:59')
UNION
(SELECT dtProcessedUTC, binData
FROM `timecull_010209` 
where TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '00:00:00' AND '00:00:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '00:15:00' AND '00:15:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '00:30:00' AND '00:30:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '00:45:00' AND '00:45:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '01:00:00' AND '01:00:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '01:15:00' AND '01:15:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '01:30:00' AND '01:30:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '01:45:00' AND '01:45:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '02:00:00' AND '02:00:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '02:15:00' AND '02:15:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '02:30:00' AND '02:30:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '02:45:00' AND '02:45:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '03:00:00' AND '03:00:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '03:15:00' AND '03:15:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '03:30:00' AND '03:30:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '03:45:00' AND '03:45:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '04:00:00' AND '04:00:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '04:15:00' AND '04:15:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '04:30:00' AND '04:30:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '04:45:00' AND '04:45:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '05:00:00' AND '05:00:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '05:15:00' AND '05:15:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '05:30:00' AND '05:30:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '05:45:00' AND '05:45:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '06:00:00' AND '06:00:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '06:15:00' AND '06:15:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '06:30:00' AND '06:30:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '06:45:00' AND '06:45:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '07:00:00' AND '07:00:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '07:15:00' AND '07:15:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '07:30:00' AND '07:30:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '07:45:00' AND '07:45:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '08:00:00' AND '08:00:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '08:15:00' AND '08:15:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '08:30:00' AND '08:30:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '08:45:00' AND '08:45:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '09:00:00' AND '09:00:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '09:15:00' AND '09:15:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '09:30:00' AND '09:30:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '09:45:00' AND '09:45:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '10:00:00' AND '10:00:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '10:15:00' AND '10:15:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '10:30:00' AND '10:30:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '10:45:00' AND '10:45:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '11:00:00' AND '11:00:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '11:15:00' AND '11:15:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '11:30:00' AND '11:30:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '11:45:00' AND '11:45:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '12:00:00' AND '12:00:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '12:15:00' AND '12:15:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '12:30:00' AND '12:30:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '12:45:00' AND '12:45:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '13:00:00' AND '13:00:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '13:15:00' AND '13:15:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '13:30:00' AND '13:30:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '13:45:00' AND '13:45:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '14:00:00' AND '14:00:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '14:15:00' AND '14:15:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '14:30:00' AND '14:30:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '14:45:00' AND '14:45:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '15:00:00' AND '15:00:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '15:15:00' AND '15:15:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '15:30:00' AND '15:30:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '15:45:00' AND '15:45:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '16:00:00' AND '16:00:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '16:15:00' AND '16:15:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '16:30:00' AND '16:30:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '16:45:00' AND '16:45:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '17:00:00' AND '17:00:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '17:15:00' AND '17:15:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '17:30:00' AND '17:30:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '17:45:00' AND '17:45:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '18:00:00' AND '18:00:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '18:15:00' AND '18:15:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '18:30:00' AND '18:30:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '18:45:00' AND '18:45:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '19:00:00' AND '19:00:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '19:15:00' AND '19:15:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '19:30:00' AND '19:30:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '19:45:00' AND '19:45:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '20:00:00' AND '20:00:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '20:15:00' AND '20:15:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '20:30:00' AND '20:30:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '20:45:00' AND '20:45:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '21:00:00' AND '21:00:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '21:15:00' AND '21:15:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '21:30:00' AND '21:30:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '21:45:00' AND '21:45:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '22:00:00' AND '22:00:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '22:15:00' AND '22:15:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '22:30:00' AND '22:30:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '22:45:00' AND '22:45:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '23:00:00' AND '23:00:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '23:15:00' AND '23:15:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '23:30:00' AND '23:30:59'
OR  TIME(dtProcessedUTC) BETWEEN '23:45:00' AND '23:45:59')
UNION
(SELECT dtProcessedUTC, binData
FROM `timecull_010309`
...
```

Comment: Having separate tables for each day is rather bad design... perhaps you should consider [partitioning](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/partitioning.html) instead?

Comment: @eggyal I agree.  This is a legacy database.  Regarding with Mike's solution with the query, is there any way to automate export to CSV from within the query so I can loop through the dates and make one per day?  I understand it's a bad design but we don't have the resources and time to replace it yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about:

```
(SELECT dtProcessedUTC, binData
FROM `timecull_010109` 
where MINUTE(dtProcessedUTC) % 15 = 0)
UNION
(SELECT dtProcessedUTC, binData
FROM `timecull_010209` 
where MINUTE(dtProcessedUTC) % 15 = 0)
...etc
```

Comment: Many thanks!  This drastically speed up the process.

Comment: Is there any way to automate export to CSV from within the query so I can loop through the dates and make one per day?

Comment: You could try a combination of cron and this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/356605/811240