# How can I export a csv file of the sql data with php?

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I currently have an app that displays about 4,000 items. I am pulling this from a mysql database. I am trying to create a button that will force a download of all of the items from the database into a csv file. How can I go about this?

**csv.php**

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=data.csv');

$output = fopen('php://output', 'w');

fputcsv($output, array('Column 1', 'Column 2', 'Column 3'));

mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'root');
mysql_select_db('wp_xroads');
$rows = mysql_query('SELECT first_name,last_name,phone FROM bags');

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rows)) fputcsv($output, $row);
?>
```

**html**

```
<div class="col-md-2">
  <!-- Button to trigger csv file exporting -->
    <form action="csv.php" method="get">
        <a class="btn btn-success" type="submit" target="_blank">
          Export CSV <span class="badge"><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-save-file'></span></span>
        </a>
    </form>
</div>
```

thanks in advance.
-ken

Comment: https://gist.github.com/apocratus/936404

Comment: Whats wrong whit your code?

Comment: @yesitsme , how would I link the the button in the html to the script?

Comment: Possible Dupe http://stackoverflow.com/a/356605/4535386

Comment: I'm crying, just completed the answer with complete instructions how OP can achieve it and now can't post it

Comment: it won't let you post?

Answer (score 2):

the `SELECT INTO OUTFILE` is the opposite of `LOAD DATA FILE`. This puts the results of the select statement into the specified file. No slow, zanny, non-performant php looping. The export_options clause is in the same flavor of the options in `LOAD DATA INFILE`.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select-into.html

```
SELECT col1,col2,col3 INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/result.txt'
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
  FROM test_table;


SELECT first_name,last_name,phone INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/myBags.txt'
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
  FROM bags;
```

Comment: just left ya a comment (notice his * and from) @BK435

Comment: hey @drew-pierce, Is what you provided the query I would be using to get the csv file? would I just link the php file to an <a> tag? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Check out bottom of edit above. how you call it is up to you (remember, they are writing to your file system :<). But it could be in a protected area somewhere in your app. Just about anywhere. So you want this to be more of an admin rights thingie.

Comment: That select statement can be as complicated as you want. It can be a huge join, computed columns, you name it.

Comment: Let me give it a try :) thank you