# How to output MySQL query results in csv format in Windows environment?

Tags: mysql, windows, powershell, csv

Is there an easy way to run a MySQL query from the PowerShell command line and output the results into a csv formatted file?

This question is the same as [How to output MySQL query results in CSV format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356578/how-to-output-mysql-query-results-in-csv-format/29503241#29503241) except in Windows. I had to figure it out in PowerShell but my answer didn't belong on the linux question. So here's the Windows+PowerShell sibling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stan's answer from [How to output MySQL query results in CSV format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356578/how-to-output-mysql-query-results-in-csv-format/29503241#29503241), adapted for Windows PowerShell

```
mysql my_database_name -u root | Out-File .\my_output_file.csv
```

This gives me a mysql prompt, but without the usual `mysql >` at the start. I type:

```
source C:\Aboslute\Path\With Spac es\Without\Quotes\To\my_select_statement.sql
```

It gives an error message and exits if there is a problem with the command, or gives me the empty prompt if the command executed successfully. I type `exit` to finish up.