# mysql.exe output CSV file in Windows

Tags: mysql, windows

```
mysql -u username -p"password" DbName -h host.com.us < inputFile.sql > outputFile.csv
```

I'm using the above command to run a query that will output the file locally. The file is only delimited by tabs. 
I have seen several answers that use shell command and I need formatting commands for **Windows command prompt**.

Comment: This seems to work https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32856809/how-to-output-mysql-query-results-in-csv-format-in-windows-environment

Comment: @NanoPish out-file doesn't work in windows command prompt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following command should do what you want at a PowerShell command prompt on Windows:

```
Get-Content inputFile.sql | mysql -u username -p'password' DbName -h host.com.us | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace "\t","," } | Out-File outputFile.csv
```

Note that I've written the above out using the full names of the PowerShell cmdlets for clarity. One would typically use the aliases gc and % for Get-Content and ForEach-Object respectively.

A wrinkle that often catches me is that PowerShell uses a 16-bit Unicode encoding by default, so the outputFile.csv produced by the above example command line will be 16-bit Unicode. The Out-File cmdlet has an -Encoding parameter to allow you to make a different choice, such as UTF8. The above command could be rewritten as:

```
gc inputFile.sql | mysql -u username -p'password' dbName -h host.com.us | % { $_ -replace "\t","," } | Out-File -Encoding utf8 outputFile.csv
```

Edit: Changed password delimiters to single quotes to prevent PowerShell from attempting string interpolations.

Comment: "The splatting operator '@' cannot be used to reference variables in an expression. '@S2d' can be used only as an argume
nt to a command. To reference variables in an expression use '$S2d'."

Comment: @user3704920 I need a little more context to understand your comment

Comment: my apologies. It's not recognizing the connection password as a string. Sees the characters as commands.

Comment: Ah, likewise apologies - if you enclose the password in single quotes 'thus' instead of double quotes ("not like this") then PowerShell shouldn't  interfere with it - I'll edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: same issue with single quotes. Odd.

gc '/Users/first.last/Desktop/queryHere.sql' | mysql -u 'first.last' -p'KS2d&0j89j(@&jSjsJ!' DBName -h host.com.co.uk | % { $_ -replace "\t","," } | Out-File -Encoding utf8 '/Users/first.last/Desktop/myfile.csv'

Comment: As you say, odd! I tried the parameter -p'KS2d&0j89j(@&jSjsJ!' in my environment (Windows 10 version 1709, PowerShell version 5.1.16299.248) and MySQL gave me "Access denied" which is what I'd expect - no sign of string manipulation there.  Which versions of Windows and PowerShell do you have?

Comment: windows 7 pro.
CLRVersion                     2.0.50727.8762
BuildVersion                   6.1.7601.17514
PSVersion                      2.0

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165912/discussion-between-dan-blanchard-and-user3704920).