# MySQL INTO OUTFILE issue with new lines in content

Tags: mysql, shell, carriage-return

I'm exporting a database report with a shell file. If I run the query in PHPMyAdmin the file comes out fine, new lines at the end of each row in the database only.

However when I run the query in my shell script using outfile to generate the file I get /n, /r and /r/n in some of the columns content. I can't work out what causes this or how to avoid it.

The issue only seems to be caused in the colour column which is the third in the example export.

**Query:**

```
mysql $MYSQLOPTS << EOFMYSQL
SELECT Product_Name, Item_Size, Item_Colour, Item_Price, Current_Stock, Item_Price * Current_Stock AS Stock_Value
FROM Items
ORDER BY Product_Name
INTO OUTFILE '$FILE'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
EOFMYSQL
```

**Example result:**

```
"Scarf_in_Peach","ONE SIZE","12/04-B2B2 ",10.00,3,30.00
"Scarf_in_Pink","ONE SIZE ","11/06-odds-C1C12100",10.00,0,0.00
"Scarf_in_Red","ONE SIZE ","11/06-B7B2-C1C12100",10.00,0,0.00
"Scarf_in_Sand_","ONE SIZE","11/06-B1I3-C1C12100
",10.00,0,0.00
"Scarf_in_Sand_/_Blue_Flowers","ONE SIZE","12/04-B2E2-C1C12100 ",10.00,4,40.00
"Scarf_in_Teal","ONE SIZE","11/06-B5G1-C1C12100
",10.00,0,0.00
"Scarf_in_Teal_/_Red_Flowers","ONE SIZE","12/04 - B2B2 ",10.00,1,10.00
"Sunrise_Skinnies","16","ODD-R1S009-1-BLUE",20.00,0,0.00
"Sunrise_Skinnies","8","ODD-R1S009-1

BLUE",20.00,0,0.00
```

Comment: Did you test your data to see if you actually have spaces (i.e. \n) in your field? I'm asking because at the end I see spaces of some of the records, maybe you also have `\n`

Comment: In the database some of them do have line breaks, however when i export to CSV from PHPmyAdmin I don't. Even when I don't select "Remove carriage return/line feed characters within columns" They are fine.

Comment: In your query you could replace carriage return and line feed characters with empty string.

Comment: Could you check out [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/356578/3664960)

Comment: @davejal I can't see anything in that question relating to extra line breaks in column content.

Comment: @Shadow that does seem to work if i change the colour column in the select to `REPLACE(REPLACE(Item_Colour, CHAR(13), ' '), CHAR(10), ' ')` Though a way to escape all columns without the long string would be ideal but it will suffice for this script. Thank you.

Comment: So that answer helped you? Would a simple trim over each column help?

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options:

1. Replace carriage return and line feed characters with empty string within your query. Pro: it is completely up to you what characters you filter out and from which fields. Con: you have to create expression for each affected field manually.
2. Use [FIELDS ESCAPED BY character](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select-into.html) option of the `SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE ...` command:

> FIELDS ESCAPED BY controls how to write special characters. If the
>   FIELDS ESCAPED BY character is not empty, it is used when necessary to
>   avoid ambiguity as a prefix that precedes following characters on
>   output:
>
> - The FIELDS ESCAPED BY character
> - The FIELDS [OPTIONALLY] ENCLOSED BY character
> - The first character of the FIELDS TERMINATED BY and LINES TERMINATED BY values
> - ASCII NUL (the zero-valued byte; what is actually written following the escape character is ASCII “0”, not a zero-valued byte)
>
> The FIELDS TERMINATED BY, ENCLOSED BY, ESCAPED BY, or LINES TERMINATED
>   BY characters must be escaped so that you can read the file back in
>   reliably. ASCII NUL is escaped to make it easier to view with some
>   pagers.

Pro: this is a fast and standard approach, that you can easily apply to all export functionality using this approach. Con: less flexible. For example, if the lines terminated by option is set to `\n`, then `\r` is not going to be escaped, which can still cause some issues on some systems.