# Removing characters from a CSV file

Tags: mysql, bash, csv, sed

I have a CSV file, that contains data exported from a mySQL table. In one of the fields, there is a newline character, which "splits" the field into 2 lines. I'm trying to remove this newline character, but can't seem to do it.

Also, the same field may contain double quotes and commas, which gives me trouble when I enclose the fields with `"` terminate them with `,` when I exported the table. So I used `|` to terminate the fields instead, and don't enclose the fields with anything.

When I `cat` the file on a linux machine, the field looks like this

```
13"\
58,20,"3
```

What the field is supposed to look like is

```
13"58,20,"3
```

When I used the vi "hex editor" (`:%!xxd`) to check the hex values of the line, I get

```
31 33 22 5c 0a 35 38 2c 32 30 2c 22 33
```

I tried using sed

```
sed -e 's/\\\n//'
```

and

```
sed -e 's/\x5c\x0a//'
```

to remove the newline, but they didn't work. How can I format the field to what it's supposed to look like?

Comment: These seems like it might be relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/356578/how-to-output-mysql-query-results-in-csv-format

Comment: What does your original data look like?

Comment: In mysql, the field looks like this `13"<newline>58,20,"3`. The <newline> just means that the `58,20,"3` string appears on the next line.

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
$ sed '/\\$/{N; s/\\\n//}' file
13"58,20,"3
```

`/\\$/`  selects lines that end with `\`.  For those lines, we read in the next line (command `N`) and then we do a substitution to remove the unwanted `\` and newline: `s/\\\n//`.

Lines that do not end with `\` are passed through unchanged.

This approach assumes that continued lines are continued just one time.  If there were to be lines with two or more continuations, we would need a loop.

Comment: This works for the most part. But for some reason, there are a handful of lines where the line is still split after the first double quotes, with the same `\\\n`

Comment: @Rayne OK.  What's different about those lines?  Is there whitespace after the `\` on those lines?  Something else?

Comment: No, they're the same, containing `\x5c\x0a`.

Comment: BTW, the field with this newline problem isn't the last column, it is somewhere in the middle, so I used `sed '/\\/{N; s/\\\n//}'` instead.

Comment: Can you show me an example of a series of  lines where this code doesn't work?

Answer (score 2):

One option to handle this on the MySQL side would to use `REPLACE()` and remove the newline characters from the column (or columns) which contain them:

```
SELECT REPLACE(col, '\n', '')
FROM yourTable
INTO OUTFILE '/output.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working for me. I included a `*` in `SELECT *, REPLACE(col, '\n', '')` as otherwise, it only returns the field. However, the field value is still split.

Comment: Which fields do you want to export?  List them all, along with the replaced one.

Comment: In the same REPLACE statement? I tried `SELECT REPLACE(col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, '\n', '')` and it returned an error about syntax error at `col4, col5'. I don't think REPLACE expects more than 3 arguments.

Comment: @Rayne No, `REPLACE` does one column at a time.

Comment: I have 16 columns, I don't think having 16 REPLACE is the elegant way?

Comment: You never mentioned this in your OP.  Even so, you could use dynamic SQL and it would not be so painful.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, using the HEX function showed me that I have 2 characters at the end of the field CHAR(13) and CHAR(10) - CR and LF so the solution is to replace both characters - ie

REPLACE(REPLACE(postcode,'\r',''),'\n','')