# How can I import MySQL database in neo4j on Windows?

Tags: mysql, import, neo4j

I am continuously looking for a decent tutorial for importing MySQL database in neo4j but I didn't find anyone easily applicable. I am using neo4j version 3.0.3 and MySQL version 8.2.

You can help me any good tutorial or a tool that can dump MySQL database directly into neo4j, but both of them should target Windows OS.

Thank you.

Comment: neo4j is a graph database and MySQL is SQL database. You will have to define nodes/relationships for data available in  SQL. Because nature of both DBs is different , I don't think you will have any application to do that. I would suggest you to write one script which will read data from MySQL and convert it into required node/relationship format and then dump to neo4j.

Answer (score 0):

H,

Michael has made such a tool, but I have never used it.
Take a look at this repo : https://github.com/jexp/neo4j-rdbms-import

Usually I make some SQL queries and I save them into a CSV file (@see [How to output MySQL query results in CSV format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356578/how-to-output-mysql-query-results-in-csv-format)).

After I load them into Neo4j with the `LOAD CSV` (@see http://jexp.de/blog/2014/06/load-csv-into-neo4j-quickly-and-successfully/)

Cheers