# Mysql output data in csv without using outfile in query

Tags: mysql

In the following command how can i output the data to be separated by comma(i.e, csv) ,I want the output in csv but i do not want to use the `into outfile` .Any way of doing this by changuing the query,

```
  mysql -uroot -ppassword -h112.30.16.11 -e 'select * from Employee.conditions' > /home/tom/preweb/static/users/aa.com/output.csv
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to output MySQL query results in CSV format?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/356578/how-to-output-mysql-query-results-in-csv-format)

Comment: select * from Employee.conditions
INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/output.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';

Comment: `into outfile` always generates the output in the same server as that of host. So, if you want the result in a separate server, mysql command is the way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, note each column name and delimiters will have to be added separately.

```
mysql -uroot -ppassword -h112.30.16.11 -e 'SELECT CONCAT(col1, ',', col2, ',', col3) FROM agents;' > /home/tom/preweb/static/users/aa.com/output.csv
```

Update based on comment:

This can be made to by dynamic by using prepared statements, in this case the table name should be added in the first parameter where it says `'table-name'`

```
mysql -uroot -ppassword -h112.30.16.11 -e "SET @VTable = 'table-name'; SET @VAllCols = CONCAT('SELECT CONCAT(',(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(COLUMN_NAME SEPARATOR ',\',\',') FROM information_schema.columns WHERE TABLE_NAME = @VTable GROUP BY table_name),') FROM ', @VTable, ';'); PREPARE stmt FROM @VAllCols; EXECUTE stmt; DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;" > /home/tom/preweb/static/users/aa.com/output.csv
```

Let me know if you need anything else like column headings.

Regards,

James

Comment: This works but how to concat in the case of select * from table;

Comment: This is badass. Thanks!