# Mysql query with csv download

Tags: php, mysql, csv

Based on an old post ([Export MYSQL Date to CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17850181/export-mysql-date-to-csv)) i try to create an sql query with .csv download option. The date range picker is appear, but doesn't give any records, and the downloaded file is empty too...:( I'm a newbie in sql, and i think the problem with is the sql query.
Here is my code:

```
                <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
                <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.js">
                </script>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css"
                    rel="stylesheet">
                        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
                        jQuery(function() {
                        jQuery( "#from" ).datepicker({
                        defaultDate: "+1w",
                        changeMonth: true,
                        changeYear: true,
                        numberOfMonths: 1,
                        dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
                        onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
                        $( "#to" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate );
                        }
                        });
                        jQuery( "#to" ).datepicker({
                        defaultDate: "+1w",
                        changeMonth: true,
                        changeYear: true,
                        numberOfMonths: 1,
                        dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
                        onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
                        jQuery( "#from" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate", selectedDate );
                        }
                        });
                        });
                        </script>
                        <h1> Reporting Info</h1>
                        <form method="post">
    <p>Select a date range: </p><label style="color:#FFF;" for="from">From</label>
                        <input type="text" id="from" name="from" />
                        <label style="color:#FFF;" for="to" >to</label>
                        <input type="text" id="to" name="to" />
                        <input name="export" type="submit" value="Sort" />
                        </form>
                        <?php
                        $from = $_POST['from'];
                        $to = $_POST['to'];
                        echo "from: " . $from;
                        echo " to: " . $to;
                        $hostname = "localhost";
                        $dbusername = "username";
                        $dbname = "dbname";
                        $dbpassword = "password";
                        $link = mysqli_connect($hostname, $dbusername, $dbpassword, $dbname);    
                        if (!$link)
                        { 
    die('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') ' . mysqli_connect_error()); 
                        } 
               $sql = "SELECT order_number, order_total,m1uzl_virtuemart_orders.created_on,
                order_item_name, first_name, email, order_status_code 
                FROM m1uzl_virtuemart_orders, m1uzl_virtuemart_order_items, 
                m1uzl_virtuemart_order_userinfos, m1uzl_virtuemart_orderstates 
                WHERE m1uzl_virtuemart_orders.created_on = 
                m1uzl_virtuemart_order_items.created_on AND 
                m1uzl_virtuemart_order_items.created_on = 
                m1uzl_virtuemart_order_userinfos.created_on AND 
                m1uzl_virtuemart_orders.created_on >= STR_TO_DATE
                ('" . $from . "', '%Y-%m-%d')AND 
                m1uzl_virtuemart_orders.created_on <=  STR_TO_DATE
                ('" . $to . "', '%Y-%m-%d'))AND order_status_code='C'";

                        if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)) {
                            echo "
                            <table width=100% border='1px'>
        <tr align='center' bgcolor='#999999'>
        <td>Név</td><td>Tagkód</td><td>Termék</td>
        <td>Összeg</td><td>Dátum</td><td>Befizető azonosító</td>
                            </tr>
                            ";

                               while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
                                    $nev = $row['first_name'];
                                    $tagkod = $row['email'];
                                    $termek =  $row['order_item_name'];
                                    $osszeg =  $row['order_total'];
                                    $datum =  $row['m1uzl_virtuemart_orders.created_on'];
                                    $befizaz =  $row['order_number'];

                                    echo " <tr align='center'><td> " . $nev;
                                    echo "</td><td> " . $tagkod;
                                    echo " </td><td> " . $termek;
                                    echo " </td><td> " . $osszeg;
                                    echo "</td><td> " . $datum;
                                    echo "</td><td> " . $befizaz;
                                    echo " </td></tr> ";
                            }
                                }
                                echo "</table>";


         echo "<form action='export.php'> <input type='submit' 
    name='export' value= 'Export CSV'></form>";

                            mysqli_close($link);
                            ?>
```

And the export.php file:

```
    <?php
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="befizetesek.csv"');

        $hostname = "localhost";
        $dbusername = "username";
        $dbname = "dbname";
        $dbpassword = "password";

    $dbhandle = mysql_connect($hostname, $dbusername, $dbpassword) 
      or die("Nem sikerült kapcsolódni az adatbázishoz");

    $selected = mysql_select_db($dbname,$dbhandle) 
      or die("Nincs kiválasztva adatbázis tábla");

    $query ="SELECT order_number, order_total, 
m1uzl_virtuemart_orders.created_on, order_item_name, first_name, email, 
order_status_code
FROM m1uzl_virtuemart_orders, m1uzl_virtuemart_order_items, 
m1uzl_virtuemart_order_userinfos, m1uzl_virtuemart_orderstates
WHERE m1uzl_virtuemart_orders.created_on = 
m1uzl_virtuemart_order_items.created_on
AND m1uzl_virtuemart_order_items.created_on = m1uzl_virtuemart_order_userinfos.created_on
AND ((m1uzl_virtuemart_orders.created_on >= '$from') AND 
(m1uzl_virtuemart_orders.created_on <= '$to'))
AND order_status_code='C'";

$export = mysql_query ($query ) or die ( "Sql error : " . mysql_error( ) );

    $fields = mysql_num_fields ( $export );

    for ( $i = 0; $i < $fields; $i++ )
    {
        $header .= mysql_field_name( $export , $i ) .";" . "\t";
    }

    while( $row = mysql_fetch_row( $export ) )
    {
        $line = '';
        foreach( $row as $value )
        {                                            
            if ( ( !isset( $value ) ) || ( $value == "" ) )
            {
                $value = "\t";
            }
            else
            {
                $value = str_replace( '"' , '""' , $value );
                $value = $value . '|' . "\t";
            }
            $line .= $value;
        }
        $data .= trim( $line ) . "\n";
    }
    $data = str_replace( "\r" , "" , $data );

    if ( $data == "" )
    {
        $data = "\n(0) Records Found!\n";                        
    }

    print "$header\n$data";


    exit();
    ?>
```

You can see the page is http://teszt.tvep.hu/tranzakciok-letoltese.html

Any help greatly appreciate!

Comment: you don't want to use php/javascript for this and certainly not mysql_* functions. There is an exellent built in facility called SELECT INTO OUTFILE

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/356578/how-to-output-mysql-query-results-in-csv-format

Comment: Please format your code snippets with correct indenting that it can be read easily.

Comment: @e4c5:Thanks for your suggestion, but i need that the user can download the file, not store on the server.