# SQL - how to make a daily export of tables

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, wamp

Right now, I'm develop a site using WAMP with the PhpMyAdmin and I'm wondering if it's possible to create a schedule event that will export couple of tables (or even all of the database) as a csv file to the server?

The purpose is to back it up to my PC with backup PC-program that will use the ftp.

What I've got so far is

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE 
    EVENT `archive_blogs` 
    ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY STARTS '2017-01-13 03:00:00' 
    DO BEGIN

    SELECT * FROM orders
    INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/orders.csv'
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
    ENCLOSED BY '"'
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'

    END */$$

DELIMITER ;
```

But it gives error (I tried it on the PhpMyAdmin).

Is there a better way to do that?
Is there a way to do that to all of the tables in one shot?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Run it as a cron job (at jobs in case of windows) from your PC. Try following command which is taken from other SO answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/12843017/1012809

```
mysql your_db -h localhost -u root -pPasswd < query.txt | tr '\t' ','
```

Contents of query.txt

```
SELECT * FROM orders;
```

Even better, give a try to `mysqldump` command. Use the tools specifically built for tasks.