# converting .sql to .csv while parsing html

Tags: mysql, csv

I'm trying to export a mysql table into csv format, by running this command in mysql command line

```
    mysql -u root -p mydb -e "select * from mytable" -B | sed "s/'/\'/;s/\t/\",\"/g;s/^/\"/;s/$/\"/;s/\n//g" > mytable.csv
```

however there are many html tags and characters so is there anyway i could add a command to parse the html???

Comment: Isn't it better? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356578/how-to-output-mysql-query-results-in-csv-format

Comment: @BorLaze yeah that is actually cool i have checked it before asking this question, but the thing is the table contains html tags and i want them removed, so do you think there is a cool and easy way to get that done??

Comment: *"HTML ... characters"* ... meaning numeric character and character entity [references](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references), like `&nbsp;`, `&#160;`, and/or `&#xa0;`?

Comment: Yeah plus tags like <p></p>