# How to generate and export a big CSV file from my PHP server?

Tags: php, mysql, node.js, csv

My server can be PHP or nodeJS, prefer staying in PHP but if it can't be done/better in node i'll appreciate the answer.

I want to generate and export a very big CSV file, the problem is that I can't load all the data from MySQL once, so currently I limit my data to some amount which doesn't crash the app, but it's slow and most data won't be exported.

I thought of this solutions to generate and export the CSV file:

1. Send 1..N calls to my server, each call will generate Part1...PartN CSV and the browser will append them [won't the browser crash?]
2. In one request, stream the data to the browser, but then how does the browser start downloading the file?

I don't mind the client will wait a lot, just want a good way to export ~200MB csv from the data I got in MySQL.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This is a nice solution using Mysql notation:

```
SELECT *
INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/dbexport.csv' 
FIELDS ENCLOSED BY '"' 
TERMINATED BY ';' 
ESCAPED BY '"' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
FROM tables;
```

Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/356605/5476782) answer too.

You could consider also use a .tsb (tab separated file) it does make no difference for you:

```
mysql your_database -e "select * from tables" -B > export.tsv
```

Comment: Its a great answer but i need to process the data in the server before sending it back to the browser, any other idea?

Comment: I do not get what you mean, this way **everything happens in the server**. Results are in your server, in the `/tmp/` folder, in the `dbexport.csv` file, so you can parse it in the server.

Comment: Parsing such a large file causes memory exhaustion, because the array which fills it get too large for the app to hold.

To solve this i can read only part of the file at a time, but then i don't need the file, i can get run a partial queries and process it, save to a multiply files / append to a single file, and then upload it somehow (?) back to the client browser.

if you know how to send a 200mb~ file to the browser i'll be grateful

Comment: in order to parse the data small files will help you with memory. Then, in order to flush 200Mb of data to browser, I see pagination is the best for you. Sort your data somehow, to be sent in slices (20 to 100 elements at a time), then organize requests like `/mydbcontent/?ini=0&size=100` and flush it in arrays of json data.