# MySQL query splitting unexpectedly in Bash Script

Tags: mysql, bash

I am having issues and not understanding what the underlying cause is.

I have a table that has these three fields:

```
______________________________________________
|   cid    |    order_id    |    TxRefNum    |
----------------------------------------------
```

I am making a simple call in my bash script (there is literally no other code to start with)

```
#!/bin/bash

mysql --login-path=main-data -e "SELECT 
    cid,
    order_id,
    TxRefNum 
FROM database.orders_temp" |

while read this that other; do

    echo "$this  ||  $that  ||  $other"
done
```

I would expect to see the following:

```
__________________________________________________________
|    29    |    F0VIc - CHATEAU ROOFIN    |   5555555    |
----------------------------------------------------------
```

Instead my script is splitting the string `$that` into two different strings ..  The echo is actually:

```
___________________________________________________
|    29    |    F0VIc    |    - CHATEAU ROOFIN    |
---------------------------------------------------
```

Do I have to set a delimiter when setting my variables in my while loop??  I am truly stumped!!

Comment: Your data might contain the delimiter. Quick way to test is by adding a replace in your query in which you just replace space with underscore. Also quick word of advice: Avoid using keywords/reserved words as parameters/variables: `this` is not the handiest name for the parameter.

Comment: LOL I realize `this` (no pun intended)  --  Those obviously aren't my "real" variable names ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Getting output from the `mysql` command formatted in an intelligent way is problematic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356578/how-to-output-mysql-query-results-in-csv-format?answertab=votes#tab-top). In your case bash is interpreting the  as a delimiter. You need to split a different way. I was able to get this working. You'll note the `|` in the query as well at the `IFS` line at the tope

```
#!/bin/bash

IFS='|' # set the delimiter
mysql --login-path=main-data -e "SELECT
    29 as cid, '|',
    'F0VIc - CHATEAU ROOFIN' as order_id,
    '|',
    5555555 as TxRefNum
FROM dual" |
while read this that other; do
    echo "$this  ||  $that  ||  $other"
done
```