# Export MySQL tables to CSV

Tags: mysql, database, csv

According to the [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqldump.html) you should be able to export to data to CSV files:

> The mysqldump command can also generate output in CSV, other delimited text, or XML format.

But the document doesn't reveal how? Can anybody help?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump-delimited-text.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to output MySQL query results in CSV format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356578/how-to-output-mysql-query-results-in-csv-format)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM `database_name`.`table_name` INTO OUTFILE 'path_to_folder/filename.csv' FIELDS ENCLOSED BY '"' TERMINATED BY ';' ESCAPED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';"
```

This is how you do it.

Comment: How does this use `mysqldump`?