# MySql command line csv

Tags: mysql, csv, command-line

Is there a way to use the following command to output in comma separated instead of tab separated.

```
echo "select col1, col2, col3 from newtable" | mysql --column-names > data.csv
```

It outputs the following.

```
col1    col2    col3   
1       Test    Test 1
2       Test    Test 2
3       Test    Test 3
```

how do I output a comma seperated file.

Comment: Hope this could be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356578/how-to-output-mysql-query-results-in-csv-format

Comment: This question is not duplicate of linked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use **tr** to replace tabulations by commas:

```
echo "select col1, col2, col3 from newtable" | mysql --column-names | tr "\t" ";" > data.csv
```