# How to write MySQL procedure output directly to file?

Tags: mysql, procedure

[It is quite simple to write an MySQL query result directly to a CSV file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356578/how-to-output-mysql-query-results-in-csv-format):

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable INTO OUTFILE '/my/file.csv'
```

How can I write the table output of a procedure directly to a file, i.e. something alike this?

```
CALL MyProc('MyPar1') INTO OUTFILE '/my/file.csv'
```

The procedure should not be changed.

Comment: Not tested but.... If the procedure returns a table, why can't you `SELECT CALL....` into a file (don't even know if this is permitted in MySQL, but it would be the first thing I would try).

Comment: Why don't you write the `SELECT * FROM MyTable INTO OUTFILE '/my/file.csv'` into the stored procedure and use a params to control the table name and the output path?  Please remember to protect against SQL injections if you are going to use `PREPARE/EXECUTE` to allow dynamic SQL execution..