# export to disk csv using pipe as delimiter in myql

Tags: mysql, csv, export-to-csv

I need a CSV from a remote mysql server (so "TO OUTFILE" is not possible) for further processing.
The issue is the fields are text that usually contains tabs (\t) so is not possible to use *sed* or *awk* to post-process and separate fields as we will end with more columns than expected for some rows.

My first approach reading Mysql manual is:

```
content=""$(mysql -u my_user -pthepass -h remote.sql.com -D my_db -s -e "${query}" --delimiter="|")
```

but to no avail. I get tab separated csv.

is there any way avoiding to make a replacement after the data is loaded?

Comment: I think  you're looking for this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/2601837/1606432

Comment: No. That precisely what I MUST avoid. Replacing characters is not possible as we have tabs everywhere