# rails - Exporting a huge CSV file consumes all RAM in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, ruby-on-rails-5

So my app exports a 11.5 MB CSV file and uses basically all of the RAM that never gets freed.

The data for the CSV is taken from the DB, and in the case mentioned above the whole thing is being exported.

I am using Ruby 2.4.1 standard CSV library in the following fashion:

`export_helper.rb`:

```
CSV.open('full_report.csv', 'wb', encoding: UTF-8) do |file|
  data = Model.scope1(param).scope2(param).includes(:model1, :model2)
  data.each do |item|
    file << [
      item.method1,
      item.method2,
      item.methid3
    ]
  end
  # repeat for other models - approx. 5 other similar loops
end
```

and then in the controller:

```
generator = ExportHelper::ReportGenerator.new
generator.full_report
respond_to do |format|
  format.csv do
    send_file(
      "#{Rails.root}/full_report.csv",
      filename: 'full_report.csv',
      type: :csv,
      disposition: :attachment
    )
  end
end
```

After a single request the puma processes load 55% of the whole server's RAM and stay like that until eventually run out of memory completely.

For instance in [this article](https://dalibornasevic.com/posts/68-processing-large-csv-files-with-ruby) generating a million-lines 75 MB CSV file required only 1 MB of RAM. But there is no DB querying involved.

The server has 1015 MB RAM + 400 MB of swap memory.

So my questions are:

- What exactly consumes so much memory? Is it the CSV generation or the communication with the DB?
- Am I doing something wrong and missing a memory leak? Or is it just how the library works?
- Is there way to free up the memory without restarting puma workers?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is your DB and how many rows are exported totally?

Comment: it's MySQL and the full report file contains 81500 rows

Comment: Use @eikes answer with `find_each` for medium solution.

Comment: Use this answer for the best solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356578/how-to-output-mysql-query-results-in-csv-format

Comment: Don't use @eikes suggestion about streaming: nginx + `send_file` >> streaming

Comment: @PavelMikhailyuk thanks! why is streaming a bad idea?

Comment: Google about "slow clients", nginx, puma threads.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Instead of `each` you should be using [`find_each`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Batches.html#method-i-find_each), which is specifically for cases like this, because it will instantiate the Models in batches and release them afterwards, whereas `each` will instantiate all of them at once.

```
CSV.open('full_report.csv', 'wb', encoding: UTF-8) do |file|
  Model.scope1(param).find_each do |item|
    file << [
      item.method1
    ]
  end
end
```

Furthermore you should stream the CSV instead of writing it to memory or disk before sending it to the browser:

```
format.csv do
  headers["Content-Type"] = "text/csv"
  headers["Content-disposition"] = "attachment; filename=\"full_report.csv\""

  # streaming_headers
  # nginx doc: Setting this to "no" will allow unbuffered responses suitable for Comet and HTTP streaming applications
  headers['X-Accel-Buffering'] = 'no'
  headers["Cache-Control"] ||= "no-cache"

  # Rack::ETag 2.2.x no longer respects 'Cache-Control'
  # https://github.com/rack/rack/commit/0371c69a0850e1b21448df96698e2926359f17fe#diff-1bc61e69628f29acd74010b83f44d041
  headers["Last-Modified"] = Time.current.httpdate

  headers.delete("Content-Length")
  response.status = 200

  header = ['Method 1', 'Method 2']
  csv_options = { col_sep: ";" }

  csv_enumerator = Enumerator.new do |y|
    y << CSV::Row.new(header, header).to_s(csv_options)
    Model.scope1(param).find_each do |item|
      y << CSV::Row.new(header, [item.method1, item.method2]).to_s(csv_options)
    end
  end

  # setting the body to an enumerator, rails will iterate this enumerator
  self.response_body = csv_enumerator
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! Using `find_each` helped to reduce memory load from 55% to 20%. However, it never gets released. So roughly 4 exports like this would exhaust the whole RAM. Is there a solution to this?

Comment: @mityakoval use a lower value for the [`batch_size`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Batches/ClassMethods/find_each) configuration option. This will help with the memory usage but note that it will have a bad impact on the performance.

Answer (score 3):

Apart from using [find_each](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Batches.html#method-i-find_each), you should try running the `ReportGenerator` code in a background job with [ActiveJob](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html). As background jobs run in seperate processes, when they are killed memory is released back to the OS.

So you could try something like this:

- A user requests some report(CSV, PDF, Excel)
- Some controller enqeues a `ReportGeneratorJob`, and a confirmation is displayed to the user
- The job is performed and an email sent with the download link/file.

Comment: Yeah, I also thought about it. But unfortunately, it has to be the full-duplex request.

Comment: @mityakoval, if you need to do it synchronously, use ActiveJob anyway but instead of calling `perform_later` call `perform_now` with a high priority queue. You will have some additional delay but the report would still be created on a separate thread.

Comment: Wow! Didn't think of this option. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Tried this approach, and unfortunately the job is executed in the main thread :_(

Answer (score 0):

Beware tho, you can easily improve ActiveRecord side, but then when sending response through Rails, it will all end up in memory buffer in the Response object: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/http/response.rb#L110

You also need to take use of live streaming feature to pass the data to the client directly without buffering: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#live-streaming-of-arbitrary-data