# MySQL: wiered chopping for string when using "SELECT INTO OUTFILE"

Tags: python, mysql, database, mysql-workbench, select-into-outfile

I exported two fields: `name` and `header` from the database using:

```
SELECT name, header 
INTO OUTFILE '/var/lib/mysql-files/myfile.txt'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '<xx>' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
FROM mytable;
```

One record has this `header` value:

> {'Date': 'Fri, 19 Apr 2019 07:23:14 GMT', 'Server': 'Apache', 'Vary':
>   'Qualys-Scan', 'Strict-Transport-Security':
>   'max-age=31536000;includeSubDomains;preload', 'Set-Cookie':
>   'ASP.NET_SessionId=ivoa5bhet0s2ygkylmimvkie; path=/; secure;
>   HttpOnly;SameSite=strict,
>   SC_ANALYTICS_GLOBAL_COOKIE=12f133ea5080403692b4ce458fd1a540;
>   expires=Thu, 19-Apr-2029 07:23:14 GMT; path=/; secure;
>   HttpOnly;SameSite=strict,
>   SC_ANALYTICS_SESSION_COOKIE=336B597E7A534D6393C57DF11E047484|1|ivoa5bhet0s2ygkylmimvkie;
>   path=/; secure; HttpOnly;SameSite=strict,
>   incap_ses_885_270026=cDp/VlO1AHgshF9F6SZIDGJ3uVwAAAAAg7DwpecyehBCyhXgoYO5GA==;
>   path=/; Domain=.zurich.co.uk, ___utmvmykuNyVY=dlNaoEsuXSO; path=/;
>   Max-Age=900, ___utmvaykuNyVY=nWJx01KvGT; path=/; Max-Age=900,
>   ___utmvbykuNyVY=JZy
>       XEtOwalQ: PtR; path=/; Max-Age=900', 'X-Content-Type-Options': 'nosniff', 'X-XSS-Protection': '1; mode=block', 'Cache-Control':
>   'private', 'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8', 'Keep-Alive':
>   'timeout=5, max=10', 'Connection': 'Keep-Alive', 'X-Iinfo':
>   '8-3925806-3925807 NNNN CT(73 151 0) RT(1555658593583 5) q(0 0 3 0)
>   r(6 6) U5', 'X-CDN': 'Incapsula', 'Content-Encoding': 'gzip',
>   'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked'}

It is exported as:

> https://z.co.uk`<xx>`{'Date': 'Fri, 19 Apr 2019 07:23:14 GMT',
>   'Server': 'Apache', 'Vary': 'Qualys-Scan',
>   'Strict-Transport-Security':
>   'max-age=31536000;includeSubDomains;preload', 'Set-Cookie':
>   'ASP.NET_SessionId=ivoa5bhet0s2ygkylmimvkie; path=/; secure;
>   HttpOnly;SameSite=strict,
>   SC_ANALYTICS_GLOBAL_COOKIE=12f133ea5080403692b4ce458fd1a540;
>   expires=Thu, 19-Apr-2029 07:23:14 GMT; path=/; secure;
>   HttpOnly;SameSite=strict,
>   SC_ANALYTICS_SESSION_COOKIE=336B597E7A534D6393C57DF11E047484|1|ivoa5bhet0s2ygkylmimvkie;
>   path=/; secure; HttpOnly;SameSite=strict,
>   incap_ses_885_270026=cDp/VlO1AHgshF9F6SZIDGJ3uVwAAAAAg7DwpecyehBCyhXgoYO5GA==;
>   path=/; Domain=.zurich.co.uk, ___utmvmykuNyVY=dlNaoEsuXSO; path=/;
>   Max-Age=900, __utmvaykuNyVY=nWJx01KvGT; path=/; Max-Age=900,
>   ___utmvbykuNyVY=JZy

And in a new line (please note that it begins with a tab that's why stack overflow displays it as a code):

> ```
> XEtOwalQ: PtR; path=/; Max-Age=900', 'X-Content-Type-Options': 'nosniff', 'X-XSS-Protection': '1; mode=block', 'Cache-Control':
> ```
>
> 'private', 'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8', 'Keep-Alive':
>   'timeout=5, max=10', 'Connection': 'Keep-Alive', 'X-Iinfo':
>   '8-3925806-3925807 NNNN CT(73 151 0) RT(1555658593583 5) q(0 0 3 0)
>   r(6 6) U5', 'X-CDN': 'Incapsula', 'Content-Encoding': 'gzip',
>   'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked'}

Why this has happened? How to avoid this?

It is causing me a big problem and appear in many other record (but not all).

I need to read the file lines using python, and python identify the chopped line as two lines instead of one, which makes the lines do not conform to the line format that I process with python and I get error saying `out of index`.

Comment: Maybe you really have end of line `\n` in that place?

Comment: How to ignore the \n and only consider end line if it ends with `}`

Comment: In the file the `\n` character is always considered end of line. If it is not critical for you, you can replace `\n` to a space or something in this column with `REPLACE` statement.

Comment: I prefer to replace after exporting into file. Any idea how to do this in Linux?

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/a/35123787/5320906

Answer (score 0):

Something like this (not tested):

```
with open('/var/lib/mysql-files/myfile.txt') as f:
    lines = f.read().splitlines()
i = 0
lines2 = []
while i<len(lines):
    if ('{' in lines[i]) and ('}' not in lines[i]):
        l = lines[i] + ' ' + lines[i+1] + '\n'
        i += 1
    else:
        l = lines[i] + '\n'
    lines2.append(l)
    i += 1

with open('/var/lib/mysql-files/fixed.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.writelines(lines2)
```