# How to export a CSV file from the MySQL command line

Tags: mysql, sql, select, xampp, into-outfile

I have a MySQL database containing a single table which is used as a temporary storage point for manipulating and querying data sets and is periodically deleted and replaced with new data. What I would like to be able to do is export the data from the MySQL command line to use for other purposes. I am using the XAMPP Apache server package with phpMyAdmin on Windows 10.

The issue I am having is the INTO OUTFILE syntax I am using returns an error relating to '\n'. Below is an example of the syntax:

```
SELECT *  
FROM tablename  
WHERE work_complete = 'Yes' 
INTO OUTFILE 'C:\file path for the file to be exported to\file_name.csv'   
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY "''"   
ESCAPED BY '\'  
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

I have spent some time researching this without any luck, I have even tried using

```
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
```

but the error remained the same

```
ERROR: Unknown command '\''.
   ->     LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';
```

If anyone could provide any tips that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I output MySQL query results in CSV format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356578/how-can-i-output-mysql-query-results-in-csv-format)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not in `LINES TERMINATED BY` but in `ESCAPED BY`.

This:

```
ESCAPED BY '\'
```

Is invalid syntax, because the backslash is interpreted as an escape character for the following quote. A decent text editor should let you see that.

You need to escape the backslash, like so:

```
ESCAPED BY '\\'
```

Alternatively, you can also use `'\b'`:

```
ESCAPED BY '\b'
```

Another probem is that `OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED` accepts only a single character, while you are giving it two single quotes.

In your query:

```
SELECT *  FROM tablename WHERE work_complete = 'Yes' 
INTO OUTFILE 'C:\file path for the file to be exported to\file_name.csv'   
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY "'" ESCAPED BY '\\'  
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

Comment: I have amended the ESCAPED BY as per the recommendation now I am presented with "ERROR 1083 (42000): Field separator argument is not what is expected; check the manual
MariaDB [db]>"

Comment: @jasw: I see. You need to change `OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY "''"` to `OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY "'"`. This option accepts a single character, while you are passing two. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
SELECT *  
FROM tablename  
#WHERE work_complete = 'Yes' 
INTO OUTFILE 'C:\file path for the file to be exported to\file_name.csv'   
FIELDS ENCLOSED BY '"' 
TERMINATED BY ';' 
ESCAPED BY '"' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';
```

I used some other syntax as you and deleted the OPTIONALLY which mysql doesn't like at that place

Comment: Now its returning an error informing me that the file already exists (which it doesn't) I have changed the file name but still returns the same error "ERROR 1086 (HY000): File 'C:file pathexport csv filescompleted_tasks.csv' already exists"

Comment: Does MySQL have a preferred file path / destination where it stores exports? or is it happy to store where specified?

Comment: if secure file was enabled yes it is the bin folder but you can add [client]
loose-local-infile = 1

[mysqld]
secure-file-priv = "" to your server, if it is your developer system

Comment: Out of interest, which is the optimal way with working with MySQL: using MySQL shell 8.0.19 with js and python connectors in conjunction with MySQL workbench, or XAMPP with phpMyAdmin?

Comment: there is no optimal way, i use workbench a lot, sometimes the shell for things that take too long, phpmyadmin is the same as Workbench, so test and see.what you like

Comment: I’m wanting to combine python with SQL, is there a python connector for XAMPP / phpMyAdmin?

Comment: I think that you don't read much about python python is a script language. There you can do anything like every other script language, so no need for xampp at all. If you use django or flask you got a replacement for apache for mysql connectio you can use https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/

Comment: My sole purpose for using python is for the application of data science

Comment: We always visualize the data, so flask is a must have, but if you don't need it at the time use the link to the connector and start, and use Workbench, then you don't need xammp.

Comment: Excellent that was the feedback I was seeking. As you can probably tell, I’m new to this. I have been using Excel, however it is getting to the point that it is too slow at handling large datasets