# Export MySQL json data type field directly to CSV

Tags: mysql, json, export-to-csv

Consider MySQL database (8.x) with JSON field:

```
mysql>  desc users_health;
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | int unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| user_id    | int          | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| data       | json         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| created_at | timestamp    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at | timestamp    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

In this answer there is a way to export colums to csv fields:

[How to output MySQL query results in CSV format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356578/how-to-output-mysql-query-results-in-csv-format/356605#356605)

What I would like to achieve is to export ONLY data in `data` column to CSV. This data is well organized and composed of key-value pairs like so:

```
{"email": "x@example.com", "user_id": 100, "ivr_used": false, "ivr_enabled": true, "callerids_used": true, "call-queue_used": false ...}
```

I would like that to be exported to CSV file looking like so:

```
    +--------------+-----------+----------+-------------+----------+
    | email        | user_id   | ivr_used | ivr_enabled | ...      |
    +--------------+----------+-----------+-------------+----------+
    | x@example.com| 100       | false    | true        | ...      |
    +--------------+----------+-----------+-------------+----------+
    | y@example.com| 101       | true     | true        | ...      |
    +--------------+----------+-----------+-------------+----------+
    ....
```

Is this even possible using MySQL-only solution, or do I have to fetch the data and process it somewhere else?

Partially valid solution for me would be possibility to export the data to JSON file.

Comment: You want 1 excel column per pair?

Comment: Yes, exactly. One key is one column. Every record in this table has the same exact structure in `data` column

Comment: Maybe you should just show us an example of the output you want in the CSV file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well its a bit like if the data were in columns, you have to extract each value you want from each rows data column

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(data, '$.email') as email,
       JSON_EXTRACT(data, '$.user_id') as user_id,
        . . .

FROM users_health
WHERE foo = 'bar'
INTO OUTFILE '/var/lib/mysql-files/orders.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

Comment: Thanks, that does the trick. Is there a way to prepend the file with row headers?