# MySQL query to csv output

Tags: mysql, csv, quotes

I'm trying to output query results to a csv file. I'm running this currently:

```
mysql  -u user -p  -e "$Query" --batch --raw |  tr '\t' ','  > file.csv;
```

The problem is that there are some fields that are a text/description that contains "," (comma), and that's where things get messed up.
I tried also to run only with batch/raw but still no luck.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I output MySQL query results in CSV format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356578/how-can-i-output-mysql-query-results-in-csv-format)