# How do I find out which linux-user is used to perform 'into outfile' query?(2 servers)

Tags: php, mysql

I'm performing a query in laravel that selects all products and puts the result in a csv file. This all works fine on windows, but on linux, file-permissions are preventing the action.

My query:

```
$query = 
<<<END
select * from products
INTO OUTFILE '/var/www/html/storage/feeds/products.csv'
fields TERMINATED BY '~' optionally ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
END

DB::statement($query);
```

My error:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 Can't create/write to file '/var/www/html/storage/feeds/products.csv'

I added the `www-data` user and group to the `feeds` folder, the folder is currently empty.

#### Note:

1. I've got a copy of this project running on the same server as the db is hosted, here I could just add the permissions of the `mysql` user to the `feeds` folder to fix this.
2. I'm reaching the db trough an ssh tunnel, so I do not have a `mysql` user on this system to assign access to.

A complete list of users on my system:

```
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/ash
bin:x:1:1:bin:/bin:/sbin/nologin
daemon:x:2:2:daemon:/sbin:/sbin/nologin
adm:x:3:4:adm:/var/adm:/sbin/nologin
lp:x:4:7:lp:/var/spool/lpd:/sbin/nologin
sync:x:5:0:sync:/sbin:/bin/sync
shutdown:x:6:0:shutdown:/sbin:/sbin/shutdown
halt:x:7:0:halt:/sbin:/sbin/halt
mail:x:8:12:mail:/var/mail:/sbin/nologin
news:x:9:13:news:/usr/lib/news:/sbin/nologin
uucp:x:10:14:uucp:/var/spool/uucppublic:/sbin/nologin
operator:x:11:0:operator:/root:/sbin/nologin
man:x:13:15:man:/usr/man:/sbin/nologin
postmaster:x:14:12:postmaster:/var/mail:/sbin/nologin
cron:x:16:16:cron:/var/spool/cron:/sbin/nologin
ftp:x:21:21::/var/lib/ftp:/sbin/nologin
sshd:x:22:22:sshd:/dev/null:/sbin/nologin
at:x:25:25:at:/var/spool/cron/atjobs:/sbin/nologin
squid:x:31:31:Squid:/var/cache/squid:/sbin/nologin
xfs:x:33:33:X Font Server:/etc/X11/fs:/sbin/nologin
games:x:35:35:games:/usr/games:/sbin/nologin
cyrus:x:85:12::/usr/cyrus:/sbin/nologin
vpopmail:x:89:89::/var/vpopmail:/sbin/nologin
ntp:x:123:123:NTP:/var/empty:/sbin/nologin
smmsp:x:209:209:smmsp:/var/spool/mqueue:/sbin/nologin
guest:x:405:100:guest:/dev/null:/sbin/nologin
nobody:x:65534:65534:nobody:/:/sbin/nologin
www-data:x:82:82:Linux User,,,:/home/www-data:/sbin/nologin
application:x:1000:1000:Linux User,,,:/home/application:/bin/bash
nginx:x:100:101:nginx:/var/lib/nginx:/sbin/nologin
```

EDIT:
I've tried installing mysql and mysql-client on this machine so I have a `mysql` user and group to assign to the desitnation folder, but that did not work.

EDIT2:
As suggested by @LawrenceCherone, I tried running the query by putting the file into a tmp location. This time the query did not crash, but I could not locate the file. After retrying the query, it crashed, saying the file already exists. I started looking on the mysql server and found it. Tho not a solution, it shines some light on what's happening: the file is not created on the server where I need it, but on the mysql server.

Comment: Is this really a PHP problem?

Comment: alt, save it in /tmp, then move/copy it to where you want it after DB::statement line

Comment: @NicoHaase Not sure. The query is ran by php, and there is no mysql service(nor client) on the machine, so I'm hesitant to rule it out so far.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Thanks for the tip! I will try it directly

Comment: Have you tried `chmod 0666 /var/www/html/storage/feeds`? Or even `0777`?

Comment: Is your PHP and MySql on same server?

Comment: @Justinas Yeah I tried opening up the permissions as much as possible(777). Php and mysql are on different servers.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I tried your suggestion, but I notice the file is being created on the mysql server, not the php server. Tho not a solution, it gave me a bit more insight on the context that the query is ran in. My original original setup probably tries to put the file in  `/var/www/html/storage/feeds` location on the mysql server, which does not exist.

Comment: plot thickens, yeah 2 separate servers your need to do more to move it to a diff server, like scp over the file

Comment: @Techno Then that means there is no such path on MySql server.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the commenters for guiding me into the direction of a solution.

Since it became clear to me `into outfile` is not going to put the file on the client side, but on the server side, and that getting the file from server to client would be the next objective, I decided to use the solution as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5395421/2595985):

First, I need to make sure mysql-client is installed on the php server, then add this code:

```
$host = config('database.connections.mysql.host');
$port = config('database.connections.mysql.port');
$user = config('database.connections.mysql.username');
$password = config('database.connections.mysql.password');
$database = config('database.connections.mysql.database');
$query = "select * from products";
$pattern = 's/\'/\\\'/;s/\t/\",\"/g;s/^/\"/;s/$/\"/;s/\n//g';
$filepath = '/var/www/html/storage/feeds/products.csv';
$command = "mysql -h $host -P $port -u $user --password=$password $database -e \"$query\" | sed \"$pattern\" > $filepath";
exec($command);
```

The permissions on the directory need to be of the user who runs php. I did `exec('whoami', $output);var_dump($output);die;` in php to find this out.